# Is there a statistic on the percentage of first-time questions that are deemed low quality?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Is there a statistic on the percentage of first-time questions that are deemed low quality - either a duplicate, unanswerable, mostly opinion etc and subsequently closed? I think it would be interesting to know, if only out of curiosity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. Out of 546773 questions asked by first-time authors during the past 365 days, 146185 were closed or deleted, or 27% low-quality.

Note that questions can also be deleted by their authors, or because the system [deemed them abandoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) - and not all low-quality questions get closed either. Therefore, perhaps a better metric is closed or scoring < 0, which gives us 160518 questions during the same time period and 29% low-quality for first-time authors.

Here's a gratuitous graph of low-quality posts (by the second criteria) by month over the past year:

[image: Questions closed or downvoted by month]

And the same but as a % of total questions asked by new users in each month:

[image: % of new-user questions closed or downvoted by month]

Finally, it's worth comparing this to the stats for questions from folks who've asked at least one previous question. In the past 365 days, 2477915 questions were asked by users who had asked at least one previous question on Stack Overflow, and out of these 426250 questions were closed or currently score < 0, or 17% low-quality. Note that even though the % is lower, the total number is higher - only 27% of low-quality questions come from folks who've never asked questions here before.

One last gratuitous graph: low-quality questions from new users as a % of all low-quality questions asked, by month, for the whole of Stack Overflow's history:

[image: Low-quality questions from new users as a % of all low-quality questions, by month]

Comment: April to May spike is likely because of exams suddenly coming at students

Comment: I would guess projects rather than exams, but you are likely right...

Comment: Do you have the sane graphs using SEs low quality algorithm rather than community feedback? What's the correlation?

Comment: Wow, very detailed! @gnat I'd agree, and same with the spike around Christmas time with mocks exams. It'd probably hold true if the number of new users at those times were factored in too as I'd imagine those times bring in a new influx of people.

Comment: That's... [Actually not very interesting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RG0rr.png), @Ben. Hopefully will get better soon: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267778/details-of-the-quality-score-algorithm-as-discussed-in-the-recent-podcast/267788#267788

Comment: hover over the last graph for commentary: Yes, Aug. '08 was the worst month for new users percentage-wise, but they only asked 411 low-quality questions compared to 15981 last month...

Comment: TIL the magic LQ heuristics are of the kind that can be computed from public data only :-)