# How to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

Many new users find it difficult to Stack Overflow. They make the same mistakes over and over, like asking unclear questions, no MCVE, too broad or use answers to comment.

I know that's our fault, but what if you can create a simple course to teach people how to Stack Overflow properly? We are not killing the site, we just don't know how to ask. And meta posts are boring. We need an interactive course (teacher: >1k rep users). Users will write the question and the teacher will teach how to improve the quality of the question. The course will also teach basic Stack Overflow things like how to logout, Markdown, be nice, interact with SOCVR bots... (that's too much, let's improve the questions first and then we will teach other things later). What do you think?

Comment: We already have the tour and the help center. I believe that's information enough.

Comment: It will be a long discussion. You may want to chat about this here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126451/the-so-course

Comment: I am a SO newbie and the tour doesn't have enough information. New users don't have enough rep to ask if their questions are good enough to post in chat.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent _"Users will write the question and the teacher will teach how to improve the quality of the question."_ We're doing that all the time leaving the appropriate and constructive comments. My experience is that most of the OP's simply don't read what we're telling them and miss to improve their questions all the time.

Comment: Have you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ all the way through? (It's linked from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The information is already there, but I suspect most people who are asking bad questions aren't taking the time to read it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I read that before asking questions so I don't have any poorly received questions. Good advice :)

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent: Right, so it worked. So why do we need a course to do the same thing? (Things like logging out, Markdown etc are covered elsewhere in the help centre.)

Comment: @JonSkeet We need something to force users to read some questions asking advice before asking. Maybe newbies doesn't even know.

Comment: So how exactly are you going to *force* users to take the course you're proposing? The problem isn't whether or not information is available, as your question seems to imply - it's that users don't make use of it. Your question doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet now I know that what I am proposing is really a bad idea. What about a quick test? SOCVR people say that there will be a test before asking questions.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent: It's not clear what "this" is in your previous comment. But I believe there's a new "Ask" experience which may help. I don't think a test is a great idea, to be honest...

Comment: @JonSkeet you have high rep. Let's think how to improve SO quality more.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent: I've been thinking about that a lot, and have a blog post I need to finish. But I've downvoted your question as I don't think having a course for people to ignore is the way forward.

Comment: @Jon They meant my proposal here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289144/establish-a-two-stage-question-commit-process

Comment: So now we not only have to answer people's questions for free, we have to volunteer our time to help them ask the questions in the first place? No thanks.

Comment: The only way to force someone to go through it, would be to not _let_ them post a question until they pass a basic question asking test. Hmm. Perhaps that wouldn't be such a crazy idea.

Comment: @Knossos - That's been suggested before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254448/should-so-have-a-prequalification-process-for-membership-to-weed-out-the-noise  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252829/brief-educational-quiz-before-posting-first-questions-in-popular-tags  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page/327003#327003 (the answer, not the question)   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268280/a-detect-bad-questions-course-for-repeated-poor-questioners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do you think?

Yes, I agree that many users find it difficult to ask good questions on Stack Overflow, and I even think that some of them make the same mistakes several times.

I also agree that this is rather not Stack Overflow's fault, because there is plenty of information available that guides you through the process and in principle tells you everything you need to know in order to ask good questions. Just read a bit in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

This may not be killing the site, but surely it seriously hurts it. Do you know how much effort it is to pay attention to, downvote and close bad questions? And all this while searching for the few really good questions that can and should be answered.

An interactive course for teaching how to use Stack Overflow might actually help with this, but I see two major problems with it:

- There may not be enough users volunteering to teach.
- Users who have a habit of posing bad question may not want to take the course.

That's why likely this idea won't go very far. But you are free to try it out. You could start by fleshing the idea out more (how should users know of this idea, where should the course take place, what should teachers do) and asking for voluntary teachers here on Meta (which isn't boring by the way).

Comment: I will try it myself first and then I will update the question.

Answer (score 6):

[Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147247/kate-gregory) has created an *extensive* pluralsite course title [*Using Stack Overflow and Other StackExchange Sites*](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites). I highly recommend pointing new users at this material. It has topics covering:

- Searching
- Asking your first question
- Managing your question
- "When things don't go smoothly"
- Answering Questions
- Voting, Reputation, Privileges, and Other Features
- Helping moderate

It is important to note that pluralsite is not [free](https://www.pluralsight.com/pricing), but they do offer a free trial (10 days or 200 minutes of material, whichever is lower).

---

Regarding your suggested topics, I have a few comments:

> logout

I don't think having a "course" for how to log out is a useful way to spend our time. It is literally two mouse clicks to get to the log out button.

> Markdown

Markdown can be tricky, especially if you haven't used it previously. However, Stack Exchange provides a nice editor to handle most markdown automatically. They also provide a help link and a link to [mark down specific help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the editor. If users aren't using links that are already right in their browser window, I don't know if directing them to another location for help will do much.

> be nice

This isn't something that needs to be taught. However, I just walked through the new user sign up and didn't see a prominent link to "Be Nice" (or even get redirected to the Tour...instead, I was presented with Developer Story signup). Perhaps an easier thing to do would be to present this information to the user at sign up.

> interact with SOCVR bots

This is not a new user "thing". New users need to know how to ask questions, answer questions, edit questions, up vote, and down vote. Interacting with bots in a moderation specific room, isn't a new user's goal.

Comment: "Markdown can be tricky, especially if you haven't used it previously. However, Stack Exchange provides a nice editor to handle most markdown automatically. They also provide a help link and a link to mark down specific help in the editor." You could maybe have something like a supervised course, where you learn the basics of markdown by accomplishing tasks (Insert this code example below that section, insert this link, that image, correct formatting mistakes) and this is checked automatically, so you learn by doing and supervision instead of just offering documentation. Could be mandatory.

Comment: Kind of like a requiring to have a "StackOverflow driver license" (but of course give badges out for it). So if users aren't using links you have to force them to kind of take an exam. It's not so silly as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I created a chat room [How to Write an English Question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128540). Feel free to visit it, become a Room Owner, take it over, and contribute. Or point a user toward it.

Many users simply do not understand the basics of concisely describing their problem, what they tried, and what the expected results are. Even after an hour of working with them.

Unfortunately they often blame the Stack Overflow community for their lack of clarity and experience here. It is not that we don't care that is for sure.