# Is triage review queue really working?

Tags: discussion, triage

I have been the decider on several reviews, meaning that they had 2 'reviews' with the same decision as mine, most of these have been 2 x 'Looks Ok' and 2 x 'Should be Improved', so my decision is conclusive. Only once have I been the decider on a unanimous review, this was when the question had been edited. What I ask is should I be hitting 'Should be Improved' more often, or is Triage just not really working?

Comment: Why exactly do you think the Triage is not working? Because you're doubting your own decisions?

Comment: I find it interesting when I've clicked "looks Ok" on something that others have flagged as needs improvement. I think the problem is that almost all questions can be improved slightly, and knowing where the cutoff should be seems pretty subjective.

Comment: @MattCoubrough yes, i would agree, that is what i meant by question.

Comment: @slugster yes-who wouldn't doubt their decision if it was split halfway (in saying this the obvious fix is for me to avoid triage/skip question until/unless I am sure of my decision), I think it is not really working because it seems nobody is deciding the same way, it seems to be unknown how to use it, i think people have  different ideas on how it works, who/which way is correct

Comment: I would suggest that you go over the ones where you've clicked looks okay and others haven't and try to work out why. It's getting amusing that posts are leaving the queue with 2 close votes from unsalvageable votes where 3 people think they're fine. (Either party might be wrong)

Answer (score 9):

I'll quote Shog9 from [his announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage):

> However, **first we need to make sure that works!** In particular,
>   before we start filtering questions from the home page or building a
>   queue for helpful editors, we need to make sure the two pieces we've
>   built already actually do what they're intended to.
>
> So right now, there's no visibility restrictions or helper queue.
>   After a few days, I'll come back with the results:
>
> - If it looks like things are working, we'll start dropping questions that don't "Look OK" from the home page.
> - If it's *not* working, we'll fix them. Change the guidance, the number of reviews required to complete a task, etc.
>
> Once we're all happy with both the behavior of Triage and the
>   appearance of the home page, we'll roll out a Helper/Editor workflow.

The whole point of the exercise at present is to see how the community responds to this. Declaring failure before the results have even been tabulated seems a bit premature. Personally, I'm optimistic that this design is going to work based on what I've seen so far.

Also, your vote is no more "deciding" than any of the other four votes on the posts you've reviewed. You just happened to vote last. Again, part of this exercise is to see where the line is for what the community feels is "unsalvageable" or "needs work".

Comment: I'd also point out that it is even *working* in its current form by having questions with a low quality score get flagged promptly and closed (and deleted? I've seen a fair number of unlinked questions from unsalvageable reviews in my review history).  Also, many times I've seen looking back on need improvement responses seeing an edit to the question when I look at it again later.  So even if there isn't complete functionality today, it is 'working' to some degree now.  More future functionality on the queue could make this even more streamlined in processing.

Comment: Yes I agree that it can work well, and it does do an alright job, but should we be heavier on the 'Should be improved' button then the 'looks ok'?