# Missing "VLQ" flag option in Triage Queue

Tags: discussion, triage

I came across a (turd of a) question in the Triage queue that I thought was a good fit for the Very Low Quality flag. When I clicked "unsalvageable", the flag menu was missing the VLQ option:

[image]

I have tested my flag menu on other normal questions and the First Posts queue, and the VLQ option is still there in both cases. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278382/2615940) from Servy and an attached comment from Shog9 (a moderator), suggest that the Triage Queue is going to take the place of the LQP Queue for questions. If that has already been implemented, it would make sense the that the VLQ flag is inaccessible. If it has, it would be nice to have that behavior more clearly specified.

Has the transition from LQP Queue to Triage Queue for VLQ questions been implemented? Is this why the VLQ flag option is unavailable?

BTW, the original question that prompted this has already been closed, so I intentionally excluded a link to it.

Comment: Related: [Why can questions be flagged but not closed for very low quality?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The lack of a "very low quality" flag option for posts under review is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244736/135615):

> #### Changes to VLQ flag availability
>
> So as of a few minutes ago, Very Low Quality won't be an option from
> within Triage review **or from anywhere else while a question is being
> triaged**. We're also taking this opportunity to be a bit proactive
> with another change that'll be necessary soon: **Very Low Quality
> won't be available for questions that are currently undergoing Close
> review either.**
>
> This moves VLQ one step closer to my intended purpose: catching awful
> questions that slipped through the cracks somehow. We'll see how that
> works out in practice...

The idea is that the function of the "very low quality" flag on questions is evolving to act as a way of finding things that review didn't catch. Once something is under review, there's no need to indicate that it needs to be reviewed. Spam, gibberish, etc. are addressed by the remaining flags.

I welcome this change, because I think it clarifies the purpose of the "very low quality" flag on questions, a source of recent debate.

Comment: Does one VLQ flag cause it to enter the queue, or is it multiple?

Comment: @TravisJ - From Shog9's answer: "eventually, VLQ flags are gonna send questions into Triage". A single flag kicks something into Low Quality Posts review, which I imagine will still apply (if not now, at some point) for triage. It would seem odd to require multiple flags to kick things into triage, because otherwise those single-flagged posts will just sit there unexamined.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that MSE post. That is the clarification I was looking for.

Comment: So if I cast a VLQ flag, then right after that cast a close vote (thus starting close review on the question), will it invalidate the old flag?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a recommend deletion flag to replace it?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: I don't think so, from memory it just prevents flagging by future visitors.

Answer (score 15):

The reason you cannot flag it as very low quality is because it has already received that flag in order to enter the triage queue. At which point it has been agreed upon that it is very low quality and can now move through the work flow in order to hopefully become a beautiful butterfly question (or perhaps just a crumpled up roomba candidate).

Triage workflow from [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/1026459):

[image]