# Detect close vote in triage review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I voted to close a question which later came up in the triage review. I wanted to click on "Unsalvageable", however I had only three choices:

[image]

Well, the question wasn't spam, it wasn't offensive, and it didn't require moderator attention. So I had to click on "Should Be Improved" instead of "Unsalvageable".

Is this expected thing to do? Or should the system be smart enough in this case and detect my close vote when I click on "Unsalvageable"?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The linked question is about double flagging. My question is about not able to select a close vote.

Comment: FYI: [You can no longer flag a question as very low quality if it is under review in Triage or Close Votes.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278833/)

Comment: Why did you click an action you didn't agree with rather than clicking "skip"?  I agree this should be fixed, but there's a right way to deal with it in the mean time.

Comment: @davidism Good point, skip is an other option too.