# Where is the very low quality flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

Please take a look on this question:
*[C# DateTime not working for MSSQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747654/c-sharp-datetime-not-working-for-mssql-stored-procedure)*

When I am trying to flag as very low quality then it is not present. See below:

[image]

But when I open any other question and open the flag menu then the *very low quality* flag is present. See below:

[image]

I just want to know why the *very low quality* flag is missing on *[C# DateTime not working for MSSQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747654/c-sharp-datetime-not-working-for-mssql-stored-procedure)*.

Comment: I don't see how that question fits the description of VLQ.

Comment: Upvote. Moreover, there are many questions on which one cannot place the flag he wants. These questions may be new and heavily downvoted as well as not so new.

Comment: Why do you need to flag that as VLQ?

Comment: @BoltClock: ah, triage queue. we are already reviewing the post, why push it into the queue again? In the queue the flag option is also not available.

Comment: Whether or not this particular question fits the need seems irrelevant to the fact that all the flag options you might want are not present. Unless some algorithm determines whether or not that ONE flag is displayed or not (although no other flags are so unreliably present).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That question is currently being reviewed for closure. As such, it does not require nor will it benefit from Very Low Quality flags - we already know it's potentially problematic, we're now trying to determine *how problematic it is* and *in what way.*

If you believe it should be closed, then please flag using one of the reasons listed under "it should be closed for another reason..."

Otherwise, move on.

#### See also: [Missing "VLQ" flag option in Triage Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278832/missing-vlq-flag-option-in-triage-queue)

Comment: Might be a good idea, then, to put something in the UI to indicate this? Grey out the option with an explanation, maybe. After all, close votes aren't even visible at all below a certain rep level, so there's no way for a low-rep user to actually know why the VLQ flag is/isn't present on a given question, which seems like it'd be a bit confusing.