# Why does the "low quality post" flag for questions sometimes not appear?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I came across a question and found the OP just posted a requirement without any code plus not well formatted and OP even asked for the code. The point is, I went to flag it as a "low quality post" but on this particular question, there is no option to flag it as a "low quality post." I know there are some other options like "opinion-based" or "too broad", but why can't I have an option to mark it as a "low quality post"?

[image: Flagging option missing the "very low quality" flag]

I can also post the link of the question if required.

And yet, the option appears in other questions:

[image: Flagging option containing the "very low quality" flag]

I also tried refreshing and reloading page and tab, but it didn't help either.

Comment: That’s what the downvote button is for, no? The voting system is for quality control. Flagging is for exceptional problems that require human intervention. Plus there *is* a close reason for this: Off topic -> `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior...`

Comment: @Pekka웃  but all other question  has this option and a question can be flagged to review by the community either to close or edit and other things so i wanted to leave it upto SO community so decide by flagging but as i said other options can be used but this option suppose to be there too

Comment: @Pekka웃 it doesn't mean if an option disappear than i think oh it will be appear magically in the future , just don't care now . sir with due respect , seems like you don't want this flag, ok but i would like to use this flag in case of uncertainty plus i quite convince that this is not a debugging question

Comment: Ah, so your point is the flag option shows up for some questions, but not this one? That’s different. (From what I can see of your example question, I still don’t think it’s necessarily flag-worthy, though. Either way, make sure you downvote it, too.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 your previous comment made me delete 7-8 lines of this comment but yes that what i was talking about  plus it's one the crutial flag to maintain quality on SO and about your `necessarily flag-worthy` notion , i guess i have to flag your comment as `opinion-based` . :):P:P

Comment: @Paulie_D letme answer you with a proof so i guess you don't like to wait till i answer back

Comment: with due respect smart guys always go with their solutions but all i am looking for the reason , don't know about others but i noticed it and it's here with proof but still can't understand unreasonable down-votes(although i know you ask for reason for down-votes you get only more and more ):P

Comment: It used to there... But before like 3years

Comment: @NullPoiиteя check the both images , both are taken today dude

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't care about flag or whatever.

Comment: The flagging option is, I believe, based on the rep of the OP. I *think* the threshold is around 350 based on a unrepresentative sample.

Comment: @Paulie_D nopes both questions were posted by newbies , both had repo under 15-20

Comment: The first question has a close vote (you didn't provide the link but the screenshot has the address/title). Apparently those questions cannot be flagged. I tried it on a few questions in the review queue.

Comment: Related: [Where is "very low quality" flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286971)

Comment: See also: [Fixing the disconnect between VLQ and triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946)

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks dude it's clear now,  ayhan thanks too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283357/165773):

> System hides an option to flag Very Low Quality in few cases, namely when post is:
>
> - in Triage or Close review queue
> - older than 7 days
> - of positive score

Can't be seen in the image, but the 0 scored question was in triage already as can be inferred [from the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39932466/timeline), while [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933412/mvc-issue-in-java) wasn't probably wasn't.

Comment: thanks sir but i noticed your point , thought i might missed it but i verified it and found it's untrue , i just checked this on newly posted question which has no down-votes at all showing me the option to flag it as low-quality(i can add image too if required for future readers ) and also that question in first image had no down-votes and yeah i thought to down-vote it but due to some others reasons(will start another discussion here ) i choose to flag it.

Comment: "System hides an option to flag Very Low Quality in few cases, namely when post is: * in Triage or Close review queue * older than 7 days * of positive score" ([Do not hide VLQ flag option from users who already flagged and may wish to retract](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283357/165773))