# How to flag a low quality answer when the option is missing from the flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I would like to flag [this accepted and upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075202/5366641) as low quality, because it is a link only by the definitions of SO.
[image]

However, I am not able to do this, since the *very low quality* option is missing:

[image]

The accepted answer to [Where is very low quality Flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286971/where-is-very-low-quality-flag) does not help in this situation, as the question is not currently being reviewed for closure.

Is flagging as *not an answer* ok in this situation or other action would be more appropriate?

More details:

For other answers (even to the same question) the option is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the wrong flag.

The VLQ flag does not apply to this question (it is not gibberish, unsalvageable junk, irrelevant nonsense or anything like that). If you are using the VLQ flag for this kind of question, [you are doing it wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291601).

The flag you are looking for is called "[Not an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)", and it is available in the flagging dialog.

Comment: Then why do link only answers appear in the _Review|Low Quality Posts_ queue?

Comment: Because it's a review queue. Not all posts in there need to be flagged VLQ just because they are in the queue. Some should be flagged VLQ, some NAA, some "look ok", etc.

Comment: Something is still not quite clear to me about that and I need some time to sort it out going through the meta posts I've read previously.

Comment: Read on. I advise reading the posts I linked you to. The rules for VLQ **are very simple and very clear**, and that flag does not apply to the answer you are linking. The name can be confusing, since what is generally considered "low quality" doesn't necessarily mash with SO flag definition.

Comment: @scopchanov [both NAA and VLQ will put the post in the Low-Quality Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291263/241919). As for the reason why link-only answers appear in LQRQ, because the objective of that queue is to delete/keep the post, which applies *both* for NAA and VLQ.