# The "very low quality" flag is highly misleading

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

I think this flag should be removed or the wording changed significantly for it to stop being misused and misunderstood.

Some reference questions I've read on the VLQ flag:

- [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)
- [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/)
- [Why were these “Very low quality” flags declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373)

I look at the close reasons and flags often when I'm deliberating on what should be done with a question or answer I believe is problematic for one reason or another. The "Very Low Quality" flag has the following description:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

There is some strong wording here, and the close reasons are generally broad enough, so I've only used this flag once, on an answer I felt strongly fit the given description. I raised a VLQ flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153467/12270289) for the following reasons:

1. The answer has formatting problems - this contributes to a lack of quality, but is salvageable through editing.
2. The answer is merely code accompanied with a fairly useless comment "Try following" - this can also be fixed with editing.
3. The code in the answer is in a language that doesn't match the question. This can also be fixed with editing, but as pointed out in comments, there is an [official faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) that explicitly recommends the VLQ flag be used for this point.
4. The code in the answer is **fundamentally nonsense**. It would not answer the question even if converted to any language I know of. The approach presented in the answer is not salvageable. This cannot be fixed with editing.

The way I see it, the answer doesn't really have any merits. It's wrong code in a wrong language accompanied by wrong grammar and wrong formatting, and the whole idea behind it is also wrong. To me, this is a perfect match to the description of "Very Low Quality". It has severe content problems and definitely is unsalvageable without writing an entirely new answer.

My flag was reviewed and declined. Confused, I looked to the above reference questions to discover how I might have misused it. My current understanding is that a *really, terribly awful* answer should only be **downvoted** as long as it still attempts to answer the question, and never removed. Why, then, does this flag exist for answers, if it can never possibly result in a deletion of the answer that wouldn't have also been covered by the flag reason "Not an Answer"? Further, why is there an [official faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) recommending the flag be used in situations where it seems sure to be denied? I have been mislead to flag the answer for deletion because of wording that is strongly misleading, wasting the time of both myself and the reviewer for the flag, when in reality the correct response was to downvote and move on. If the community at large has decided that bad answers should not be deleted, this decision should be available to the common user, and supported by the interface. For this reason, I think this flag should be seriously reworked or removed entirely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it

Comment: IMO it's best to just pretend the VLQ flag doesn't exist. I've never seen an answer that I would want to use it on that wouldn't fit NAA just as easily, and that way you aren't tempted to use it in edge cases like this one that are more likely to be declined.

Comment: Despite the company being enamored with "standard flags," a custom flag is always preferable in borderline cases.  Explain the problem in the flag, and if your explanation has merit, it's more likely to be handled in the way you expect.

Comment: ... or declined, or processed in 6-8 weeks because there are 400+ custom flags in the queue right now.

Comment: About item 3: Despite that the official FAQ for [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/) says to flag "Is fundamentally inapplicable to the question (a LINQ answer on a Java question or a C++ answer on a Haskell question):" as VLQ, your flag will likely be declined. I think for two reasons: 1. Not everyone remembers that is part of the FAQ, and 2. It conflicts with the general idea that an Answer that attempt to answer **any** valid Question (not necessarily the one it's attached to) should not be removed as VLQ/NAA:

Comment: @Scratte I was not aware of that FAQ... This flag really seems to be treated strangely by the community. I think at the very least some consistency in the wording and resources would do wonders.

Comment: You're not likely to get overall consensus. The only "advantage" the VLQ flag has is that it's not retained when the author edits their Answer. I don't use this flag at all, but if I understand it correctly, the post will leave the LQP queue if there's an edit. Unfortunately (again, I may be mistaken) you will not be able to re-flag the post, even if the edit doesn't make the post OK.

Answer (score 11):

Read

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

As

> This is gibberish. Nobody can fix it.

Which is unlikely to be true for any sort of posted code.  To know if code is gibberish, you would have to compile and run it; that sort of thing is above the VLQ flag's pay grade.  In short, VLQ shouldn't be used for "this code is wrong."

In general, moderator flags should not be used to judge any answer's technical merits.  That would imply that moderators have enough technical knowledge to judge all code answers regardless of language or technology; I can assure you that's not the case.

Comment: If *any sort of posted code* is generally enough to elevate an answer above being considered for VLQ, what situations are covered by the VLQ flag that aren't already covered by the "not an answer" flag?

Comment: Don't get me started on the "Not an Answer" flag.

Comment: very low quality applies to both answers & questions. Not an answer, well... not to questions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't see the option to select "Very Low Quality" when flagging questions, only answers.

Comment: hell, I was sure it existed, but it seems that you're right. It seems that it existed before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/it-shouldn-t-be-possible-to-flag-questions-as-very-low-quality

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre AFAIK there's certain requirements for the option to be available on questions. I don't know what they are but I can see the option on some questions but not others.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery IIRC it's <1wk old and no upvotes. Also it has to not be in the CV queue

Comment: @Klaycon as a moderator, there are currently a few questions tagged as "very low quality". Now how to flag a question as low quality is still a mystery but someone knows :) well this seems to explain it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286971/where-is-the-very-low-quality-flag