# Triage - why isn't the menu the other way round

Tags: feature-request

In triage, almost all the answers I mark as "unsalvageable" belong in that category because they fit either the "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" categories under "off topic".

Why, then does the menu first ask us to decide if it's spam or offensive or whatever, first? Wouldn't it make more sense to give the off-topic reasons as an initial selection, and "spam ... etc" as the sub-menu?

Comment: I think it's because they just use the same menu as they do for flagging (because that's what you're doing). But if they were to customise it, yes -- this would be good.

Answer (score 5):

Triage is just staying consistent with the flag options in any other context.  The only difference is that the "Very Low Quality" is not available, since that [would be redundant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278832/missing-vlq-flag-option-in-triage-queue/278833#278833) (that's likely how it got into triage in the first place). See the flag options even here on meta:

[image: meta flag options]

As for not "defaulting" to off-topic, even though Spam and Offensive posts are rarer than the broad swath of off-topic posts, Spam and Offensive posts are much more harmful to the site.  That's probably why they are at the top-level flag options, but the off-topic reasons are at a sub-level.  It's to make flagging spam easy to expedite its removal.