# Require or at least remind about code

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to alert users who post SO questions without code, that the user **'should'** add code if their question is related to code, which it probably is.

I see so many questions from new users that simply ask a question e.g. "why is my footer going left and not staying central"

These questions just waste everyones time including the user who posted them.

Just an idea...

**EDIT**

**So how would this work?**

If a post contains no code, then before posting, a simple message saying "Is this a question asking for coding help? If so, please include code that you've tried"

If a user does not have a rating or maybe less than 10, then also include a message "Click here to make sure you get the best out of Stackoverflow" the link to the new users section.

These are not ground breaking changes but just simply to make SO more useful to everyone. A page where you see each question with negative ratings because of lack of information gets old really fast for me.

Comment: More than code is needed the should take a complete tour through help and site before asking.

Comment: Agreed, my point is to do something instead of letting the posts through

Comment: @Louis It should proactive instead of reactive - a close vote means the question is live, it should not have got there - of course some will but the number of codeless code questions is high

Comment: Well to be honest @Louis, if new users are encouraged to read the helpcenter and are reminded to include their code in the question, they would learn how to use SO much quicker and user friendly. When I joined SO and I asked a question it got downvoted a lot, closed and discouraged me a lot.

Comment: @Louis I think the suggestion is to help improve the quality of posts so that they don't need to be closed. Isn't it better to try and insure that a question doesn't need to be closed then clutter up the close queue with more questions that will need to be closed/cleaned up?

Comment: @KevinVoorn Exactly my point - hence saying it wastes the posters time as much as everyone who wants to help

Comment: @Louis Agreed, bad choice of words... added more information

Comment: There are still -many- instances of questions getting downvoted and OPs getting berated for posting questions without code.

Answer (score 6):

We do this to an extent. When we can *clearly* determine that a user is talking about code, yet there's no code in the question, the system won't accept the question - it'll prod them by telling them there's not enough code.

The problem is detecting this reliably without being annoying, or (at worst) terribly frustrating. A big hint that code is mentioned comes in the form of what the user has linked to - if links point off site to places we know have code, and there's no code in the question, well ... we have it :)

Matching on 'code' alone gets a bit too far into the *oh you stupid a$$holes this question is about codeplex why are you asking me for code?* territory. There's also plenty of theory questions where .. well .. there's just no code. There are just too many corner cases to do this blindly, so we're doing the following:

- Quality scores are now much smarter
- Anything that's not *definitely* likely to be stellar goes into a new [triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) before it gets any real visibility
- Questions that can't be salvaged are quickly dealt with
- Questions that *can* be salvaged are, and ultimately given visibility

We're still not done, probably won't be until the end of January, but you'll see *considerably* less of these. The 'dumb' filters are still in place, just augmented with human intelligence in very small, very manageable units of work that folks don't mind doing.

But, we're not going to force everything to have a code block, or you'll see a lot of this:

```
do.why('NEEDS_CODE') = stupid;
```

Any time you say 'needs this before you can post' it's a carrot on a stick, and people quite often focus more on shutting up the filters rather than actually looking at what they're really doing. That's why we don't give *specific* reasons for rejecting posts in our existing system (beyond a few hints where it's not always likely to be obvious).

Comment: Hi Tim, how do the automated checks determine if a user is talking about code or not? Why wasn't this caught: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271278/plot-wind-vectors-with-quiver

Answer (score 3):

It should depend. I have posted several questions without code, and it makes the responses more useful to others who want to adapt it. Why should an answer that is given, only have to fit the asker of the question's situation? Not only that, but if I cant figure out how to adapt any code, then what good is it for me to try programming.

Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't the questions asked are supposed to help others. If so why then would the answers only be tailored to the asker's situation. By doing so it is only answering one person's situation, which may result in the same question being asked multiple times.