# Should a HOWTO question about launching C++ threads be closed for lacking an MCVE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, minimal-reproducible-example

I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656173/launching-stdthread-using-shared-ptr) and asked that an MCVE be provided. The asker replied to my comment suggesting that such a thing was unnecessary in the context of his question.

I'm pretty sure that my close vote was correctly chosen. Of course I'm hoping for the Meta Effect to back me up.

Was I correct in voting to close that question? If we have quality policies I think they should be applied regardless of the asker's reputation or whether the question was answered.

---

<sub>Of course I could have edited the question to improve it from my own observations, but I think we could expect that little effort being done by a +3k user themselves.</sub>

Comment: Unclear if you meant this to be a general etiquette question or a discussion of that specific post... I've assumed the former since the title implies it, but body could imply the latter.

Comment: @Shog9 I meant the particular post, maybe implied from _hoping for Meta Effect_ and explicitly showing that particular link.

Comment: As I said, could go either way. FWIW, there's a [meta-tag:specific-question] tag for this... **Edited, please review.**

Comment: @Shog9 THX, I wasn't aware of that tag.

Comment: It's one thing to acknowledge the meta effect, but I wouldn't "hope" for it lest it backfire...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I wrote in response to [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP "post some code"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760):

> ...Then there are problems that don't really need any code, at least not in the question, but where code can be a more effective way to communicate what's being done than prose would be. Doesn't even need to be real code - pseudocode works fine. Your example falls into this category - it didn't need code, but the code is easier to read than the prose, and together they help to clarify the problem in a way that either one alone wouldn't.

*Your* example falls into this category also. The asker isn't trying to debug a problem with code he's written; he's trying to write something but doesn't know how. The code exists only to help explain the context in which he's operating - it doesn't have to demonstrate a reproduceable problem, and in fact **asking for a complete program listing just asks for noise.** If you've been around for a while (and you have...) you're more than familiar with folks dumping their entire source listings into questions only to refer to a two-line section somewhere in the middle; for some problems, this is unavoidable - you need the full program (or at least *a* full program) in order to reproduce the problem. But for HOWTO questions, it is almost always counter-productive; answerers and future readers alike benefit more from brevity and code that gets straight to the point.

So no, the question shouldn't be closed.

You raised another question here, as sort of an after-thought:

> If we have quality policies I think they should be applied regardless of the asker's reputation **or whether the question was answered.**

(emphasis mine)

As much as we might hope for some platonic ideal that we could hold all questions to and thereby obtain quality, the truth is that *even questions that follow all the rules* are usually terrible; truth is, **the only good questions are the ones that get good answers.** Jeff wrote about this years ago in [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/):

> Perhaps you've noticed a theme here. Incoming questions are a universal constant, all around us in countless billions. But answers -- truly brilliant, amazing, correct answers -- are as rare as pearls. Thus, **questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl.**

You don't throw away a pearl because you don't believe the oyster should've been able to produce it. As much as it chafes to admit it, answers *are* a factor when determining the worth of a question - indeed, they are probably the most important factor. All of our rules, policies, guidelines and so on are built around two fundamental goals:

1. Encouraging useful answers
2. Helping others with the same question find those answers

The most carefully-constructed question on earth is worthless if it doesn't achieve #1 and ideally #2 as well. When asking yourself whether or not to close a question, **first and foremost ask if it will be usefully answered.** If it is, might be, or you really don't know... Then don't worry about it.

Comment: The part about answers factoring into a question's value is why we have badges [rewarding users who take the time to edit questions that they have answered with a positive score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator). If you've taken the time to write a good answer to a question, and aren't just doing it for the rep, then chances are you felt the question was worth answering - surely it deserves a bit of polishing as well.

Comment: Exactly, @boltclock - also, you maximize the value of your answers by making it easier for others to find them even if you *are* in it for the rep.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I think you are off-base and over interpreting the question asking guidelines, although my lack of C++ knowledge might be blinding me to an issue with the question that is obvious to a C++ expert.

Not every question needs to have an MCVE, just like not every question needs code.  An MCVE is critical when asking "why isn't my code working", but the OP here is not asking you to troubleshoot code.  The user asked "How do I do this", and provided an idea of what they are trying to do both in words and in code.

The title is searchable, the question seems clear, and it seems like what they are trying to accomplish would be a problem that would not be localized to just that user. Can't say if it is too broad or not, but the simplicity of the accepted answer suggests that it is not.

Comment: As shown that question obviously misses to state the exact compilation errors as required from the policy.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ again, the user doesn't ask you about compiler errors or fixing the code.  So why would telling you the complier errors be necessary?

Comment: They're actually asking _`// Is this the correct way?`_. The shortcut answer is just _No_. That's what I'd call a poorly asked question.

Comment: They're asking "how do I do something" - the "is this the correct way" bit is just a means to that end, and not the primary question. I think the answer being no may be just as obvious to the asker as it is to you. Look at the accepted answer; it doesn't even so much as address the attempted code beyond "You overcomplicate the issue", simply because it's not essential or even relevant. Sure, it *could* have - that's what I often do with my own answers to similar questions - but it doesn't have to if that's not the focus of the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair point, but anyway just a signpost of low research efforts.