# Any ideas why my question about programmatically finding details for a "certificate" object was closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601196/how-do-i-programmatically-find-which-certificate-was-used-to-sign-a-given-certif) about programmatically finding details of an SSL certificate represented by a `X509Certificate2` .NET object. It was closed as "too broad" in ten minutes.

How is this too broad? Either the .NET Framework has handles for that task (which I failed to find) or it doesn't. How would I formulate such question so that it stays and hopefully gets answered?

Comment: Closed in only ten minutes? We are getting better at this. (That said, I don't see anything glaringly wrong with your question. I wouldn't have voted to close it.)

Comment: @CodyGray The unfunniest part is I clicked through the five users who voted to close the question and only one of them has serious activity in c# tag.

Comment: I guess the words looked big and therefore intimidating to the close voters. (Definitely not to me, even though I haven't worked with SSL certs - much.)

Comment: I was one of the people who closed your question. The reason it happened so fast was most likely because your question was featured in the [socvr](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28937127#28937127) chat room. The reason I personally voted to close this question is that it is broad and requires a full tutorial-like explaination of specific functions to answer. (and the answers could be wildly different)

Comment: Don't bother pinging any of the voters - they won't be notified. Only a diamond mod closing your question will be notified in a comment. All the users who voted to close are active on meta, so they'll probably spot your question (and one has just responded).

Comment: @BoltClock I beat you to the punch. Anyways, if you want to discuss this OP you can drop into the chatroom anytime.

Comment: It doesn't need to be discussed in chat. It should be discussed *here*. On the Meta question about its closure and about how it can be improved for possible re-opening.

Comment: I, too, VTC'ed because the question failed to show an approach taken and gotten stuck on (MCVE).

Comment: @Magisch Em... I never saw any problems answering similar questions - usually the answer goes like "you use X class which has Y method and then you do Z with result and you're done"

Comment: I guess you could have an argument about wether or not we should reopen it and close it as Lacking MCVE instead. I fail to see how <Is there a way I can do $nonspecificX> is fundamentally different from the 100s of questions like these we get and close daily.

Comment: @Magisch If a minimal example was possible then I would have no problem in the first place.

Comment: @sharptooth An example certificate and example verification and example desired output would go a long way. Right now its very unspecific and broad.

Comment: It's hard to see how an example certificate would do anyone who could answer the question any good. If you know what an `X509Certificate2` object is, you don't need to see an example. Sigh, looks like the close voters were hoping to see a "debug my code" dump instead.

Comment: @CodyGray  The whole point of a MCVE is to narrow the (now too broad) question and Make sure that the answerers can clearly and completly understand what is necessary. Including a desired input and output will go a long way towards that.

Comment: It is not a "debug my code" question. You don't need an *example*. There is no "desired input and output." He's asking a very straightforward question about the existence of specific functionality in a library. It cannot be broad, the two possible answers are literally "do xyz" and "can't be done." An example would just make the question more difficult to understand and less relevant to others in the future. I know what an MCVE is; it is not required for all questions, only the "debug my code" ones.

Comment: @Magisch I crafted a neat picture with arrows and notes (and included that into the question).

Comment: @Magisch: Is the title "How do I programmatically find which certificate was used to sign a given certificate?" so hard to understand? I have no experience working directly with SSL certs and that title sounds reasonably narrowed down to me. It's not like the question is asking "what is an SSL certificate?" - *that* would be too broad.

Comment: @BoltClock With the example outlining the hierachy properly and some rewording its now alot clearer, imo. It wasn't before.  it was successfully reopened. Not sure about how good it is now, but its certainly a lot cleaner.

Comment: Haha the picture! ZOMG now it is a good question!

Comment: @CodyGray Yeap!!! I guess it would go stellar if it had a lolcat.

Comment: @Magisch: I don't know about the image, but I guess the rewording clears things up somewhat.

Comment: @sharptooth For low-traffic tags, it is virtually impossible to get questions closed without the aid of non-experts in that tag.  The fact that non-experts voted to close your question has little to do with whether or not the question was appropriately closed.

Comment: @cimmanon c# and .net are hardly low-traffic tags.

Comment: The point here is that your comment is way off.  Even in high-traffic tags, not everyone who has expertise actively participates in that tag, giving the illusion that they are not "experts" according to SO.  In fact, the technologies I used at work are ones that I have little to no activity in (but they are the ones where I hand out a lot of upvotes).

Comment: "The reason it happened so fast was most likely because your question was featured in the socvr chat room." - Maybe that has a (minor) part in the problem. The close vote threshold doesn't work very well if there is too much correlated close voting behavior. (I actually don't understand the question, but I also have no knowledge in the area, so I better shut up. :))

Comment: lack of *activity* in a tag **is no measure of knowledge**, I do not participate in many tags I am also an expert in for one simple fact. By now the reasonably questions have been asked and answered dozens of times in those tags, and unless I am close to getting a gold badge in that tag, I do not need the rep. The rest are extremely localized or are some bizarre edge case bug I have no interest in trying to solve. So just because someone does not have a bunch of rep *activity* from a tag does not mean they are unqualified, their *activity* might just be in cleaning house which you get nothing.

Comment: @CodyGray I feel it's worth pointing out that, as you are someone who does not participate in chat at all (per your own profile description), I feel you are not qualified to determine what chat is appropriate for. It's also important to note that the question was featured in chat *before* it was closed. Discussion about whether it was closed properly isn't what happened in chat. But you couldn't possibly know this, since you don't use chat.

Comment: @CodyGray LOL, it got closed as "too broad" again.

Comment: @tyler I don't care what *you* use chat for, or anyone else. It wasn't a comment that "people in chat shouldn't talk about close votes." But it is **completely inappropriate** to insist that sharptooth go to a chat room in order to figure out what the motives of the close voters were in this case **when he has already posted a question on Meta about it**. Magisch had said, *"if you want to discuss this OP you can drop into the chatroom anytime."* That is wrong, and that is what my comment was in response to.

Comment: @CodyGray Extended discussion between two users actually **always** belongs in chat; you can ask any moderator and they'll tell you the same thing.

Comment: Downvote and move on (no research shown) should have been enough... Also I think close vote actually helped the question - otherwise OP would have to post bounty to bring it back to life after adding details... One option to show research could be to list classes in same namespace that did not help at all while looking promising (i.e. X509Chain could be found that way).

Comment: @CodyGray Extended back and forth discussion between two or three users is a clear case of "not in comments but in chat"

Comment: No one said anything about "extended discussion." I feel like you and Tyler are being deliberately obtuse here. sharptooth asked for an explanation of why his question was closed. You said he can ask you in chat. No! He asked on Meta! Chat is an *optional* feature. He could ask in chat if he wanted an extended discussion, but I don't think he does. He wants to understand why his question was closed and how to fix it so it can be re-opened. That doesn't require chat.

Comment: @CodyGray If he wants an answer as to why from me (one of the original closers) then he can ask in chat. Im not obligated to answer his meta question exhaustively and was only making the offer if he valued my input on it.

Comment: I remember good old times when there was no chat and still SO was running just fine.

Answer (score 28):

I was one of five users who voted to close your question<sup>†</sup>. Since you specifically asked me in a (deleted) comment on your question about why it was closed (presumably I am the user who has the serious activity in the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag you mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317570/any-ideas-why-my-question-about-programmatically-finding-details-for-a-certific#comment312812_317570)), I will answer.

For the record, and if it's relevant, I came across your question when [it was linked to](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28937127#28937127) in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room. I did not feel pressured into voting to close your question as a result of it appearing there, nor would my actions have been different if I'd seen your question from the [main page](http://stackoverflow.com) or the [Close Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

<sup>†</sup> the first time - it seems that following your question being reopened, it was closed for being too broad and reopened a second time: I did not participate in the closing the second time.

---

The entirety of the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35601196/1) of your question is:

> In my C# code I have a X509Certificate2 which represents an SSL certificate from local certificate store. The certificate is signed with some intermediate certificate which maybe is present in the local store, maybe not.
>
> How do I know a thumbprint or anything equivalent which would let me identify which certificate was used to sign my certificate?

The default message which accompanies a question closed as too broad reads (emphasis mine):

> There are either **too many possible answers**, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

Since you hadn't posted your attempts to try this yourself, there's no code for us to go off. I felt that any answers posted could have wildly different approaches to finding out which certificate was used to sign yours, which wouldn't necessarily be helpful.

---

I see that you added

> , so using `X509Chain.Build()` will probably not work

to the question after it was closed, which shows that you had at least tried (or ruled out) *something*.

From my understanding of the 'too broad' close reason your question, in the state it was in when it was closed, *was* too broad since it didn't show what you'd tried so far. Had I seen your edits **before** others opened it, I would have voted to reopen it. Likewise, were your question shown to me in its current state, I would not have voted to close it.

---

I will point out that it was only [last week](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee?tab=reputation) that I gained sufficient reputation (3,000) to cast close-votes on questions; I can only blame this on over-exuberant application of what I interpreted the spirit of the 'too broad' close-vote reason to be.

If I was wrong to do so (and comments on the question, e.g. by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317570/any-ideas-why-my-question-about-programmatically-finding-details-for-a-certific#comment312809_317570), [BoltClock ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317570/any-ideas-why-my-question-about-programmatically-finding-details-for-a-certific#comment312816_317570), et. al. indicate so), then I apologise.

Comment: *"From my understanding of the 'too broad' close reason your question, in the state it was in when it was closed, was too broad since it didn't show what you'd tried so far."* This is not correct. "Too broad" is not a synonym for "what have you tried." There are cases of overlap, as with the "no MCVE" closure reason, but that would be for questions where the person has posted a code dump without any relevant context and/or has essentially asked the community to write a big bunch of code for him. Those should be closed, but you have to be careful with dogmatic adherence to that rule.

Comment: The thing I'd ask you to think about is whether you think this site should be a debugging service. If you require *all* questions to include a specific discussion of what has been tried and an MCVE, then you have effectively turned us into a debugging service. Personally, I don't see anything wrong with *reasonably scoped* questions about features of a particular library or language. I assume the confusion here (since none of us are apparently security certificate experts) was whether sharptooth's question was reasonably scoped. I think it is; you don't need a tutorial on certs to answer it.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'd not thought of it that way. I'll be more careful with cases like this in future.

Comment: Disregarding a confusion about what 'too broad' means, the original question didn't really give the perception of being an on-topic question, even when it can be well established now that it was. What has been improved since that initial moment is exactly that: the looks of the question, not the content. With a pretty picture as icing on the cake. And now things are chugging along nicely. That might be the kind of work that more questions need up front to cope with the fact that they require your eyes to be wide open, but there isn't much guidance about that I think.

Comment: From my understanding of the 'too broad' close reason your question, in the state it was in when it was closed, was too broad since it didn't show what you'd tried so far." Too broad ~= not enough research. Asker not done enough -> downvote because of not enough (re)search.

Comment: you might find this [@Shog9♦'s answer on "Make it easier to close job shop “gimme teh codez” questions"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/4279) insightful.

Comment: If you see close reason from the good point of view (please can you address these issues, to improve your question) seeing the original version both to broad and unclear would have helped to improve the question and it did. Note not addressing directly gimme teh codez problem, but  the issue: show us at what point you are? (broad), what do you exactly expect from answer (unclear)

Comment: Another of Shog9's answers on providing MCVEs in questions: [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760)

Comment: @BoltClock If we demand *some code* we likely get Linux kernel code.

Answer (score 15):

Since some people seem to be conflating "What have you tried" with "Too Broad," some review might be in order.

**Too Broad** is useful for two categories of questions:

1. Questions which require a book (or the better part of a book chapter) to answer, and
2. Questions that are polls, recommendations or "big lists of things."

In other words, the close reason is meant for exactly those situations that it describes: the answers are expected to be too long or too many.

Too broad doesn't mean "incomplete" or "lack of effort."  If the question isn't sufficiently researched, apply a downvote.  If there isn't enough information in the question to make it answerable, close it as "Unclear what you are asking."

We need to stop being allergic to "How do I [do something]" questions.  "How-To" questions are perfectly fine.  If the question is on-topic*, clear and not too broad (i.e. answerable), it is welcome on Stack Overflow.  If you consider such questions lazy or uninteresting, then simply leave them for someone else to answer.

*<sub>You already know what "on-topic" means; if you don't, read the Help Center's "What kinds of questions can I ask here" article.  Yes, we still have special requirements for "how do I fix my broken code" questions, including an MCVE, that don't necessarily apply to other types of questions.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree that it should have been closed, but it was linked in the [SO CVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28937127#28937127), and they've very close-vote happy.

As I understand it, your question is "how do I tell which intermediate cert signed my X509Certificate2 in my C# code", which is pretty specific.  I voted to re-open.

edit: And in mentioning the SO CVR room, I'm sure this answer will attract downvotes, which shows that the system is pretty broken, but that's why the question was closed.

Comment: We are throwing many accusations here. Users are asked to read the questions and if they are not convinced to expose their cases. I've [disagreed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28878816#28878816) with some closures and gave [specific reasons](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28879637#28879637) why it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: As one of the long standing room owners of the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) I do understand that our room might be perceived as a nasty evil voting mob. It is hard to fight such misconceptions but I can assure you that our [FAQ](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation) is clear about the rules to be followed by our regulars and our room moderation is focused on those rules. We do take re-open requests serious (as you can see from our transcript). If needed we are happy to come forward on meta and rectify moderation we have done in error.

Comment: @rene, I have a question. You say that your room is not "a nasty evil voting mob" and that "it is hard to fight such misconceptions." I imagine that it is. What does your chat room offer by way of keeping the site clean that the closure queues do not already offer? I mean, if I want to help out and vote to close some questions, why should I join [cv-plz] rather than just clicking through the queue?

Comment: @Magisch Almost no one reads FAQs or room rules.  It's like the Star Wars extended universe -- people deeply invested in the topic know it exists, but for all intents and purposes, it doesn't count.

Comment: Ugh, I read all of that and I don't see how it answers my question. I find two principal arguments: (1) having a posse improves morale, (2) "all members concentrate on a single tag at a time [to achieve] a higher chance of completing the review tasks that we process." I don't understand that second one. You complete a review task by making a decision and acting (or not) on it. What does it matter if that's all done on the same tag or not? Oh, and there are bots. Which I totally don't understand, but that's probably because I don't know anything about the chat thingadongdong.

Comment: @tristan Then take the conversation to the chatroom I just created. This extended discussion isn't appropriate here and has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104431/discussion-on-answer-by-tristan-any-ideas-why-my-question-about-programmatically).

Comment: @CodyGray The room focuses specially on questions that attract spam or VLQ/NAA answers, it also focuses on old, off-topic questions that gather new answers, and on tag cleanup/burnination efforts. It's also an open sounding board for advice on the quality of questions, and how to improve them, for new and veteran users. Probably most helpful is that all this occurs in real-time. What rene said is true; the room allows both close- and reopen-vote messages and handles them both seriously.

Comment: I think there was some confusion. I've been idling in that room for a while, and its clearly a room about Combat Vehicle Reconnaissance, not Close Vote Reviewing.