# The 'Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style' problem

Tags: discussion, self-answer, instant-self-answer

Here is the problem:

1. You begin to write a question, and you include your issue / non-working code
2. You find the answer in the meantime, and you use the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" feature.
3. Then you realize it makes no sense anymore to post the wrong non-working code in the question itself, because you have working code in the answer! And non-working code would be visual pollution because it's pointless: you have the answer already.
4. You post it, and [you get downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504375/numpy-matrix-to-tkinter-canvas) because people think "It looks like you want us to write some code for you" (which is obviously wrong -> other criticisms can be made, but not this one).

More generally, I feel that the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" philosophy is generally not welcome on Stack Overflow. Why?

[In my self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504375/numpy-matrix-to-tkinter-canvas) I really wanted to share the effort of searching for the answer, finding the right answer (okay, it was in a blog, but it took time to find the relevant one, and I had to slightly modify the code to make it work), and post it for future reference, for other people.

I have no other interest. (If it was possible, I would be okay with no voting on self-Q&A, to show that it's not to gain reputation).

Please believe me that was really done in no other interest than future reference.

Comment: Why do you remove your code from your question? If that is the most obvious way to do X, but it doesn't work, by all means, include it; it helps providing context. When a 'normal' question is answered, how many OPs remove their non-working-but-now-fixed code from their question?

Comment: @Glorfindel : it was long code because tkinter code always takes some space (much visual pollution), wrong, and really provided no interest, once you know the answer.

Comment: But if you hadn't known the answer, you'd still have to include the code in order to be helped (otherwise the question would've been closed as 'no MCVE').

Comment: Yes @Glorfindel. But that's precisely the problem I have here with self Q&A, that I wanted to discuss here. Because it's self Q&A, does really making up a wrong code make sense?

Comment: [Writing self-answered questions is hard.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d) And I have only [N=1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40356855/4751173) experience with it.

Comment: *I would be okay with no voting on self-Q&A, to show that it's not to gain reputation* The purpose of voting is to indicate/control the quality of posts on the site. If you don't want rep from self-Q&A that's one thing but we shouldn't remove the ability to vote on them.

Comment: @Glorfindel I can understand that people disagree with this meta post. But I don't understand the massive downvote. Everything I did (the original SO question and this meta SO question) was done with the only goal of sharing information. Why such a result? There's sometimes something I don't understand about internet psychology.

Comment: IDK, I didn't downvote. Recommended reading: [Why are votes on Meta so passionate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325635/why-are-votes-on-meta-so-passionate)

Comment: @Glorfindel Good reading indeed.

Comment: @Basj You say: "_you feel that the ... philosophy is generally not welcome on Stack Overflow._". Yet surely you're aware that this question references an ***anecdotal sample size of one***. Furthermore, you're being ***selective*** in your sample because I see you have at least one other self-answered question which has upvotes on both question and answer.

Comment: @CraigYoung I have experienced the same another time, and I even deleted the question (IIRC?) because of the DV and the comments were really rude. Really, I **do feel** (ok it's opinion-based) that there is a presumption of culpability when self Q&A. According to these 2 examples, people react very fast, in a very agressive manner: very negative comments, DV, while my only interest was posting for future reference. Lesson learnt: I won't self Q&A again, and I will post my working question+solutions somewhere else (personal blog, instructables, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

> Because it's self Q&A, does really making up a wrong code make sense?

No, but you're not fabricating an MCVE solely for the sake of having an MCVE here. Most fabricated ones are pretty obvious and really should be edited out because they *do* serve as nothing more than a distraction — if it's *not* obvious and otherwise indistinguishable from a real MCVE that fully demonstrates and supports a real problem description, then it serves its purpose just as well as the real code example.

You had code that didn't work prior to finding your solution; why not leave it in for context? Remember that the question has to stand on its own regardless of whether it has a self-answer.

Comment: Aside from that, the supposition made in the question is that posting the non-working code would just create pointless noise/distraction. I don't think that's necessarily true. Often, seeing the process of transformation from non-working to working code can be very instructive, both in a purely educational sense and also in adapting a *similar* Q&A to a specific problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which makes sense. What should I do with [this now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504375/numpy-matrix-to-tkinter-canvas)? All I wanted is to share the result of the time I spent, and now here's the result. This makes me a bit sad... Once again, if it was possible, I would be okay with no voting on self-Q&A, to show that it's not to gain reputation. Future reference (for myself and other people) was my only goal.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yeah, non-working code isn't inherently a distraction. It's when said code is irrelevant to the problem at hand that it becomes a distraction. You know how some users resort to posting code blocks filled with gibberish or boilerplate code to trick the quality filter? That's basically what it amounts to. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760

Comment: @Basj: If you don't think it's too late to edit your question, do so.

Comment: Look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504375/numpy-matrix-to-tkinter-canvas#comment70214002_41504375) for example: it makes no sense at all, it's a criticism which is oviously wrong. It gets upvoted... My question+answer get downvoted...

Comment: Last thing: if you have ideas to share about `More generally, I feel that the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" philosophy is generally not welcome on Stack Overflow. Why?` I would be interested.

Comment: @Basj: Yes, because your question is nothing more than a one-liner with a direct question. *Anyone* posting that sort of question is going to come off as asking the community to write code for them. Regardless of whether there's a self-answer below.

Comment: @Basj: Not welcome? [Oh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/why-is-my-jquery-not-selector-not-working-in-css) [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560018/how-do-i-make-text-shadow-and-box-shadow-use-the-text-color-on-all-browsers) I [beg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196773/why-is-this-non-float-margin-collapsing-with-a-float) [to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160136/why-does-setting-element-classname-null-result-in-class-null) [differ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441499/is-there-a-way-to-say-use-the-current-font-weight-without-making-it-lighter-bo).

Comment: But but *because* it's self-answer, `come off as asking the community to write code for them` is obviously wrong. Why do such comments appear on self-Q&A and once, more, isn't there a philosophy problem about self Q&A on SO? (Presumption of culpability...)

Comment: @Basj: Because people have tunnel vision and insist on evaluating questions absent of context, making their comments seem out of place. Good theory, poor implementation.

Comment: @BoltClock People are *supposed* to evaluate the question and the answer separately.  We don't *want* them to vote on the question based on the quality of an answer it has.  If the question merits a downvote when looked at in isolation then *it's not a good question* and the votes *should* reflect that.  It's the people that go around upvoting extremely low quality questions just because the author posted an answer that are much more problematic.

Comment: @Servy: Yes (that's why I said good theory), but you can still avoid looking like an idiot by at least acknowledging the presence of a self-answer while still evaluating the question independently of it. Something like "Note that having a self-answer does not exempt your question from our quality standards."

Comment: @Servy It seems that people don't evaluate question and answer separately. The answer I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41504376/1422096) is probably not the best answer in the world, but it doesn't deserve -2. 1) It states the source (so I don't claim authorship) 2) It contains code, originally coming from the blog, modified to make it work with nowadays versions and to show only the core of the problem (simplified code) 3) It contains a few comments. Obviously people downvoted it *because of the question*... It's a bit sad, because I really posted with the most positive attitude.

Comment: @Basj You feel that it's not a good answer, and are surprised that it's downvoted?  If you think it's not a good answer you should *expect* it to be downvoted.  If it's not a good answer we *want* it to be downvoted.  You provided a low quality answer, two people indicated that it's not a quality answer.  The system works, huzzah.  And considering that the post even got comments explaining what was wrong, and that they said nothing about the question, there's pretty compelling evidence that they voted based on the answer, not the question.

Comment: @Servy in fact, it's not a bad *answer*, it perfectly answers to the question.

Comment: @Basj Clearly those voters disagreed, and considering you yourself said that you didn't think it was a good answer just a few minutes ago, clearly it's *not* a "perfect" answer.

Comment: @Servy I never said It wasn't a good answer, I said that *I knew it wasn't "the best answer in the world" among all answers in the world on SO*, that's how I meant it.
Anyway not a big deal, but these people didn't vote according to the real technical problem that this answer totally solves. I'm not new on SO... Anyway. End of the story for me. Many hours lost on SO + meta SO discussing about just some knowledge I wanted to share :(

Comment: @Basj The entirety of your explanation in v1 of your answer was: "Here is working solution, slightly modified to make it work (some function was deprecated)". Apart from the reference link, that explanation is wholly uninformative. You've made some small improvements, but still don't explain what function was deprecated. Still don't give any clear indications as to what solves the problem. The code has a bunch of magic numbers in it; presumably unimportant code that merely sets up a way to demonstrate the solution - _but this emphasises the problem_.

Comment: @Basj If you had you simply taken the "not working" code you'd found and explained in your question: "I found this `code` at `source` but it doesn't work because of error `message`" Your question might have received UVs, and your answer DVs. Then changing your answer to explain what you fixed: * Which function is deprecated - bonus points for research on the deprecation. * Which lines are important for the overall solution .... You might have received UVs on that too.

Comment: @CraigYoung thanks, but not a big deal. I'll turn this page now ;)