# Changes to discourage debug requests

Tags: feature-request

There are an incredible number of questions asking something along the lines of "Can you please help me debug without me putting effort in".

To which the usual reaction in some people post in the comments saying "please learn how to debug, this link [here] will help; and someone who's either wanting the rep or feeling very very nice (or bored) will reply pointing out what's gone wrong.

The question is off-topic, but the people asking them likely haven't read what's on topic, so it doesn't stop them asking the question.  The generally negative reaction to these questions gives many the impression that the SO community is cold and unhelpful; which doesn't help SO or the people asking.

As questions are being typed, there's a "similar questions" to right; which absolutely reduces the number of duplicates; but doesn't help with debug questions.

I feel that there should be a static section underneath that pointing out explicitly that debug questions without effort are off topic; with links to what debugging is and a tutorial (maybe [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)).  As well as a link to the 'how to ask a question', the 'tour' and any others that may be of use.

Comment: Not *ALL* questions about debugging are off topic. There are a lot of people who ask "Meh codez are broke, fix pls" which is obviously not acceptable. But there are also questions about debugging that can be helpful on this site, we don't want to discourage those.

Comment: you can add all the tooltips , info and other helpful material you want.. But new askers never seem to actually go through them before or while asking

Comment: @EthanField Don't disagree, which is why I said "without effort" - or meant to, that seemed to get lost in an iteration :)

Comment: @UKMonkey I appreciate that but adding something which actively discourages debugging questions on the question screen which is going to be viewed by users who are both exhibiting effort and those who are not is going to discourage both of them from posting.

Comment: @SurajRao There will always be some who ignore it, sure, but the aim isn't to have 100% success, but just reduce the number.  Every 'it's not working' question is going to be different, the attempt to find similar questions will likely fail;  and I don't see why not have a link to 'how to ask' + others will discourage people from posting.

Comment: I am 100% in favor of a blanket ban on debugging questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant care to elaborate why?

Comment: While in general it would love to solve the problem of "debug my code" questions, I don't see how this particular proposal could help.

Comment: @jhpratt because they're soooo boring... _and_ they have a greater tendency to be of little use to future viewers.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to enforce (what's the line, past which you're "debugging"?) or contain (see our recent discussion [about the expansion of "MCVE"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361278/introduce-users-to-the-importance-of-an-mcve-when-asking-about-errors-with-speci/361280#comment544229_361280)) @TinyGiant, but I know where you're coming from.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I said I'm in favor of a ban, I didn't say I thought it would work, also most debugging question that contain any real value for future users (other than tips on debugging)  _could_ be asked as well-defined how-to questions. Except in cases of specific errors that are caused by a common problem. Questions about specific errors that could be caused by any number of different problems are just noise for future readers unless they have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users *are* already being given this information, and they have been for years.  You're not allowed to ask a question without being presented with the help center section on how to ask a question and being forced to explicitly acknowledge that you've read it.  People (or at least the people that ask questions like that) simply don't read the information that they're presented with on how to ask an appropriate question.  They also don't *care* what the site's rules and standards are, or whether or not their question violates them, they're just here to ask their question.

Comment: I understand that you're referring to specifically the types of users being asked about in this question, but those are some broad groups you're pointing at. Might be worth specifying that *most users* don't care.

Comment: @EthanField from the answer: "People (or at least the people that ask questions like that) [...]"  The types of people that care about the rules, want to follow them, and are willing to follow the advice given to them, don't ask questions that just dump code and say it doesn't work, because they know and care that they shouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm gonna go make a coffee and book an eye test...

Comment: @EthanField Actually I edited it in after I posted the answer and before you commented, I just felt like giving you a hard time.

Comment: Thank Jon Skeet, my eyes are saved!

Comment: Maybe you're right ... clearly my faith in humanity is too great

Comment: Still, a bunch of these questions is asked each day (I found 4 in the last 24 hours), and none of the flags seem fit. Is there anything else I can do other than downvoting and posting a comment?