# Is it possible to rephrase my question so that it is on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, editing-help

My question [Why is my C++ ATL project linking in a CIL library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203519/why-is-my-c-atl-project-linking-in-cil/) was closed and I see why. The title is rather generic, it's phrased as if it could have any number of reasons, and could be hard to answer without knowing any more.

However, I think that this question actually makes a wrong impression. In fact, it's quite unlikely to get this error message from any other action than what I describe in my own answer (which I found out some time after asking). Also, the user action to get this is not far-fetched or contrived – I think it could happen to anyone just as it did to me. And of course, the error message is not much help.

So given that there is a simple answer to the rather weird question, is it still hopeless for being on-topic, or could it be edited to be more in line with good questions? I'm looking forward to suggestions.

*Edit: The question was reopened, thanks to everyone who took part in the reassessment.*

Comment: I recall from previous meta posts that tagging a post with C++ while it is about visual-c++ specific will attract the wrong crowd. It looks like that might be the case here as well but I'll let Hans vent in his own comment...

Comment: @rene "I recall from previous meta posts that tagging a post with C++ while it is about visual-c++ specific will attract the wrong crowd." - not sure what "the wrong crowd" is. This question was closed (on my part) because it didn't post any C++ code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I can't judge, maybe it doesn't need c++ code?

Comment: @rene From the close reason "and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself", which does imply some code.

Comment: I know the close reasons @NeilButterworth and what they imply. It still looks like a project / build misconfiguration problem that doesn't need code. But if you think the question can be fixed by adding an helloworld.h and helloworld.cpp then by all means suggest that in an answer.

Comment: @Neil I honestly couldn't say what code would possibly help the question. The project wizard's output? Surely you'll acknowledge that there are tons of good questions without any code, so it seems to me the C++ tag might indeed be the biggest flaw of the question, just because it doesn't need C++ code to be completely described.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that Neil has no idea what a "project wizard" looks like.  The question was closed by highly experienced Unix programmers that probably haven't used MSVC++ in at least a decade, if ever.  Why that is a good enough reason to close the question is very murky, I can't really explain it without venting.  This Q+A is otherwise the meat-and-potatoes of SO, highly valuable to anybody that gets the same linker error.  It is very obscure, [visual-c++] programmers use wizards to keep them out of trouble like this :)   Don't worry about it getting deleted, ping me if it happens.

Comment: I will never stop linking to [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code/286760#286760) on the topic of providing code in questions. "You should **refrain** from requesting code when encountering a question where ...the question does not concern an issue with code."