# Are questions about obscure "feature" implementations valid for SO?

Tags: discussion

I recently stumbled across a weird feature of Unity's C# -> in some cases, you can ask if(this == null) and get true as a result. ReSharper, as well as other sources seem to suggest that this is "always false", but an SO question suggests that this is possible with some manual il magic.

I'd like to figure out how one would go about actually writing something like that, but I'm not sure if a question like this is valid for either SO or programming.stackexchange - it's not a problem I'm having, and it's not really a design issue, more of a technical curiousity.

Is SO appropriate for questions like this (and otherwise, is there an SE site that is?)

Comment: Yes! These deep insights into how the language works are definetly on-topic here! (And I would be glad to answer if I knew it)

Comment: Yes indeed this particular question is valid and already asked on SO as you've likely https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+when+this+can+be+null - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055068/within-a-c-sharp-instance-method-can-this-ever-be-null.

Comment: Yup, that was the question I was referencing. In that so question, SLaks gives the answer that it's possible. Is it on-topic to ask a question that is essentially "how do you do this?". It feels weird to me because I couldn't provide any code.

Comment: "How do I" questions have been a topic of contention on the site for many years. Some people are vehemently opposed to any "how do I" question regardless of how well-written and well-researched it is, [just because the asker didn't provide any code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286757), even when there is literally nothing to start with. Some are merely concerned about homework questions (a valid concern, but policy has always been to treat them as any other question). Others worry that the scope of a question could end up far greater than the asker (or *they* themself) bargained for.

Comment: Personally, I evaluate "how do I" questions on a case-by-case basis and find a good many reasonably scoped and very answerable. I've asked a few such questions of my own that have been well-received. Many, but not all, of these types of questions will require a reviewer have domain knowledge to tell just how answerable they are, but the community has a bad habit of thinking they know just as well as or better than the experts do. I've had to reopen a few questions others deemed too broad even though I generally think my reading comprehension skills are wanting...