# Add shorthand links for specific meta faq to the markdown editing help

Tags: feature-request, markdown, magic-links

So a bit of context. There are many times I want to help question askers on SO (or commenters) with their problems but their question contains details that they should fix. Now, this is normal but the issue comes when you want to explain it by linking the asker to an in-depth explanation of why and how.

For example, there are many new users who put their questions and code in images. I know there are many ways to deal with this but I believe the best response to help would be to link them to [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Now yes I just did that in this post BUT that's ONLY because I've noticed that link in 1 question randomly when browsing. Currently, new users who want to help with a comment have access to the markdown guide which has a shorthand for stuff like the minimal reproducible example, how to ask and how to answer. But a new user might not know about the existence of the question I linked just above.

What I propose is the addition of new shorthand links such as [noimage] (probably not what would be used but I'm just making it up). This would then allow a commenter who wants to help to quickly link the asker to the related faq without having to first know the existence of the question by having had someone link it on one of their questions first.

Another example of this usefulness is I was recently linked to this question:
[Is it always a good idea to demand the OP "post some code"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757) here I was able to read about why its not always a good idea to demand code from an OP. But for something like this I would need to know about the post by having someone first link it. In fact, just for this question, I had to do quite a bit of searching just to find the post and link it.

So in a nutshell. I would like to request some new additions to the markdown editing guide that have new shorthand links to questions/answers that commenters often find useful. It's all well and good to have us go through an faq and find it ourselves but sometimes you don't have much time but want to link the OP (or commenter) to a meta resource that would be useful for them. It is these times that adding new shorthand links to these questions in the markdown guide would be useful.

---

Update: As HereticMonkey commented. A shorthand link the [FAQ index](/q/251225) Would be just as useful as an addition to the current markdown guide as if we can then guide them to look at the faq for useful information to fix a comment or question. And yes while it is on the help page I've found that the help page can be difficult to navigate to find specific information sometimes. But that is just my personal experience (Then again I am a newer user so It could be considered a fairly valid argument)

I just thought as well, that additionally, a link to a list of current canonical links, that we have, could also be just as useful as the addition of new links to specific questions as instead of needing to keep adding new shorthand we can just go to a page and get them. So let me explain that a bit more. For this part of the suggestion I'm not suggesting a shorthand link but rather a link in the guide that a commenter or asker could click and then be able to grab canonical links from. I still think the original idea is the best but this is still another good connected feature idea (in my opinion at least).

Comment: Bookmark the one's you find useful. Easy to locate them in your own profile that way

Comment: @charlietfl But that doesn't solve the issue mentioned. Yes **I** can find them easily but **Others** who may not even know of the question might not be able to. The point of the change would be to benefit those who do not know and provide a faster, easier way of linking users to posts to help fix their errors.

Comment: "but sometimes you don't have much time" If you truly want to help the person, make the time. Otherwise, the best I think we should do is put a link to [the FAQ Index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/215552) on there... But that's already linked on [the main help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). There's a saying, "you can guide a horse to water, but you can't make 'em drink"...

Comment: @HereticMonkey An interesting saying but we currently don't even "guide a horse to water". We'd like to think everyone has read every little thing in the help page and FAQ but that's just not true. Even a new addition of a link to the index like you suggested would be very useful. I wish I was joking when I say I only discovered the FAQ index when I made this post but that would be lying. If I have this problem then it is very likely others do as well. and while experienced users probably won't need the additions it is very useful to newer users who are just learning SO and still want to help.

Comment: Actually I just had the idea that maybe another possible way to do this would be a link to an faq section which contains a list of cannonical shorthand links. That way if we know what we want we could just quickly go to that page and grab the link without needing to find each exact document. On second thought that just leads to the same solution of linking the FAQ index but I think my idea is interesting enough to warrant it's own comment but probably isn't the right way to go about adding something like this.