# Maximum of 6 Reviews per Item in Triage Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, triage

Sometimes there are questions in the Triage queue that completely split the community (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6532806)). This is understandable as reviewing is sometimes a subjective thing, however when a question gets 2 reviews for each of Unsalvageable, Should Be Improved, and Looks OK, there is clearly no consensus.

In this case, is there any benefit of taking the question to a 7th review? It would be almost pot luck as to the outcome and, when [the full grand plan is implemented for the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), there could be consequences for the post that are unintended.

Any thoughts on this?

---

Perhaps [this is a better example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6533058). As you can see the "consensus" is that the post **Looks OK**, but a further review (I'm assuming moments later) found the post **Should Be Improved**. The irony is that the post itself was closed and later deleted!

---

Thanks to *Turnerj* who provided [an even better example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6615109).

Comment: The review item I posted has since become unreviewable after I took it as an example. I suspect this is because of the time passed rather than the number of reviews taken. Usually it would go to a 7th review.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6533058) is a better example.

Comment: I'd actually suggest 5 is a better maximum.  If 5 reviews are mixed, then it's not clearly any one value.  But on the other hand, they may take this into account when programming the machine learning side of things; you can have 'mixed but chose X', 'mixed but chose Y'.  Yes, it might be somewhat random/arbitrary, but over a large sample you probably will get a reasonable outcome.

Comment: [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6615109). Has 7 reviews with 3 "Looks OK".