# Clearly incorrect triage reviews - Does SO keep track?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6987421

One "Looks OK" and three "Unsalvageable" at this point.  I've seen this several times, where a bad question is getting one or two "Looks OK" triage reviews.

Does SO keep track of the minority votes here to guide the users towards better triage judgement?

EDIT: As has been pointed out, *that* specific question is on the border between *Unsalvageable* and *Needs Improvement*, but I've seen totally irredeemable questions with one or two *Looks OK* votes.  Clearly there will be differences of opinion; however, a triage voting history that is *consistently* contrary to the general consensus could be indicative of deliberate manipulation or (more likely) poor judgement.

Comment: My mind went yesterday and I accidentally clicked Looks Okay, went straight to the question and voted to close.

Comment: See, I wouldn't have called that example either. 'should be improved' maybe, because it's unclear. But it's not utter junk either - there's clearly a question in there, and some code to start from.

Comment: I would think it does for the purposes of review bans, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Theres worse questions than this making it onto the front page.

Comment: In the mind of a veteran SO user. I think every question could be improved. Some questions are Ok as is.

Comment: `In the mind of a veteran SO user.` dude...

Comment: Do 'needs improvement' is showed as 'Looks OK'?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier His account is 18 months old. That's like a decade in internet time.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea That doesn't make the question a good question.  Lots of bad questions make it to the homepage; the whole point of triage is *to try to stop that from happening*.

Comment: I'd certainly appreciate being notified (hopefully more gracefully than via ban) if my reviews are consistently against the community consensus, so that I can adjust my standards.  Right now looking through my review history requires clicking reviews one-by-one.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. And it is failing to do that. If questions like this are not getting on there but worse questions are, then the standards are not being consistent.

Comment: I had [one review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6615109) where 2 people did Unsalvageable, 2 did Should Be Improved and 3 did Looks OK. (Can't remember why I picked Unsalvageable but likely was it sounding like wanting software/library recommendations). Different people have different ways of looking at a question.

Comment: Related: [Maximum of 6 Reviews per Item in Triage Queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280771/3899908)

Comment: If the majority of reviewers are not paying attention, than penalizing minority voters could be counter-effective. These could actually be _right_.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, of course it keeps track - you're *linking to* a historical record after all.

But what you're really asking is... Does the system *do anything* with these cases?

No, not directly. It's *expected* that there'll be minority opinions - in both directions - on many questions; that's why multiple reviews are required for consensus!

The truth is, most questions are borderline: they *could* be answered, perhaps even answered well; there are relatively few questions that are irredeemably bad or unquestionably good, although [we do try to identify some of those cases to use as *audits*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278440/are-there-audits-in-the-triage-review-queue/278512#278512).

Since these *are* tracked, it is possible for moderators to manually block reviewers when they see egregiously-bad reviews - "looks OK" on spam and the like. Which they do.

But your example is hardly egregious; although poorly-written, it can be answered (and has been). I don't agree that it "looks OK", but I don't agree that it's unsalvageable either (it may well be a duplicate though). I see similar disagreements in the comments *here*, which should illustrate pretty effectively how subjective this all is.

The goal of Triage is to quickly "bucket" questions, not to decide their fate once and for all. We have to be willing to give up a little bit of accuracy in individual cases in exchange for the ability to handle a large volume of questions more appropriately on average.

Comment: WOAH, there. So a "Looks OK" on a post that was deleted by spam flags, generates an automatic flag?

Comment: No. But moderators reviewing spam and finding it was mis-triaged may.

Comment: For me, a large problem is with Triage itself. Sometimes I come across a question in Triage that should be closed, for whatever reason (eg, asking to debug something). For me, the "wording" of the question Might need improvement and/or looks ok, but the question itself doesn't belong on SO. So, what do to?

Comment: @cmroanirgo unsalvagable beats need improvement, need improvement beats looks ok, unsalvagable beats looks ok.

Comment: @Braiam dammit man, you make a simple thing sound like some kind of roshambo.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's... a good thing?

Answer (score 2):

In completion to Shog9's Answer, i want to add that I posted a question on Meta Exchange two days ago regarding the consensus's history: [Can the review's history also include the consensus of our reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/can-the-reviews-history-also-include-the-consensus-of-our-reviews?noredirect=1#comment813692_248338)

I hope this suggestion would be considered for all sites.