# Why does this question "Look OK"?

Tags: discussion, triage, quality-improvement

I have just taken a look for the answer to my question, and so I now understand that a question "Looks OK" if three reviewers have voted "Looks OK".

Regardless of your opinion of the quality of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9902289) (not that I don't respect your opinion, but that's not the reason I'm asking this question) why would SO deem it to "Look OK"?

SO is community led and four reviewers don't think this is OK, three do. This seems like a flaw in the system to me and maybe a reason why SO is now, in my humble opinion, getting bogged down with poor questions and answers.

Is my understanding wrong about three "Looks OK" votes overriding any number of "Requires Editing" & "Unsalvageable" (and therefore there is another reason why this question "Looks OK")?

If my understanding isn't wrong, are there plans to change this to help improve the quality of SO?

Comment: It sounds like you assume that the Triage queue is used to prevent questions from being visible to you.  That is not the way it works.  It, at best, is used to determine the likelihood that SO users get this question on their personalized front page.  No idea if that system is actually in place.  Getting rid of it completely is much, much harder.  Systems put into place over the past 3 years only optimize to minimize the number of complaints, not to improve the quality of the Q+A.  Deletion in particular causes many complaints.

Comment: 3 of any kind of vote completes the review.  It's just that in this case, after 6 reviews it was tied 2-2-2.  So the 7th and deciding review happened to be "OK".  That's by design.  And honestly, "Requires Editing" is closer in spirit to "OK" than "Unsalvageable"

Comment: The broad range of responses to that review really says it all.

Comment: If you see it as a scale 'Requires Editing' is between 'Looks OK' and 'Unsalvageable', so on average the voters think it requires editing.

Comment: There's an obvious wrongness to the way that triage voting works on display here; if one of the "unsalvageable" voters had a *higher* opinion of the post and voted for "requires editing", then the net result would've been *lower*. That plainly shouldn't be how things work.

Comment: @MarkAmery Of course, had that happened, the post would've gone to the NI queue, nothing about it would have actually been fixed, and it would have been displayed normally, just a little bit later.  The fundamental problem is that the people going to the review queue just aren't going to sit down and spend a bunch of time *really* fixing a problematic post.  Either it gets closed, or it doesn't, so "requires editing" is functionally equivalent to "looks okay".

Comment: @ryanyuyu do you want to make your comment the answer, maybe incorporating the observation Mark Amery made in his comment?  It is clear my understanding wasn't exactly correct; in as much as I hadn't realised that three of any kind of vote completes the review.  I think that would be useful to make clear in an answer...

Comment: @Servy seems to me that something should be put in place to push the onus firmly back onto the questioner to improve the question until it definitively passes triage.

Comment: @lukkea That's what happens when you close a question, which is of course what the vast majority of reviewers are unwilling to do, regardless of how much its merited.

Comment: @MarkAmery I précised your comment on the answer; I will delete my comment if you would prefer to make the comment yourself.

Comment: Related: [Maximum of 6 Reviews per Item in Triage Queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280771/maximum-of-6-reviews-per-item-in-triage-queue)

Comment: @Servy you may be right the "requires editing" would've been no better an outcome in practice, but fixing a voting system that no reasonable person could possibly think is right can only be a positive step towards making the queue something more than a waste of time.

Comment: @MarkAmery "a voting system that no reasonable person could possibly think is right"  I reject that premise. The queue has three quite orthogonal states of the post, and the voting system reflects that.  I'll also note that you haven't even proposed an alternative system, which you are of course welcome to do. And no, trying to improve the way that an option is selected *when the selected options don't actually accomplish their goal* isn't necessarily a step towards making those options actually accomplish their goal.  It's an improvement *once you've already accomplished that by other means*.

Comment: @MarkAmery: That's a fairly classic flaw of voting systems in general, and unfortunately there are even theorems to prove that certain combinations of desirable properties are mutually exclusive. Voting is *always* inherently imperfect.

Comment: Perhaps we should take up an alternative vote system?  If your choice does not win, in this case it would be "unsalvageable," your vote moves to your second choice, which in this case would be "requires editing."  Either way, the unpopular choice would not win, and the wrong action would not have been taken, as it did here.  The "second" choice could either be specified by the user (unlikely) or simply chosen by the system (next most related choice sort of thing).

Comment: Regarding voting systems, remember [Arrow's Impossibility Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) which says that a general solution to voting that satisfies all of one specific list of reasonable expectations is not possible. While this may not be an application of that system (which is narrower than most non-technical ways one may paraphrase the result), it might be possible enough to make a voting system that would have performed better in *this* case, but making a voting system that would be better in *all* cases is a *much*, *much* taller order.

Comment: Solution: Just like you decrease your rep by 1 to downvote an answer, the same should happen for voting Looks Ok in Triage. There is very little that actually is Ok in Triage, so there needs to be a lot more disincentivizing for the easy one-click default option.

Comment: And why this question is put on hold as too broad. It's an off topic question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In triage 3 of any kind of vote completes the review. In this specific case, after 6 reviews, the question's reviews were tied 2-2-2. The 7th and deciding review happened to be "OK". So marking the review as "OK" is expected by the design of triage (final scoring 3-2-2).

Comment: This means, as Mark Amery says in his comment to the question: "if one of the 'unsalvageable' voters had a higher opinion of the post and voted for 'requires editing', then the net result would've been lower." ie: Requires Editing would have won with 3 votes.