# Title Case Title Edit Suggestions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, title

I recently across [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3471712/auguste?tab=activity&sort=revisions) recently suggested edits. I notice that most of the submissions are merely converting the titles of questions to title cases.

While they do have a few edits where they're adding in some code blocks, or fixing the obvious spelling mistakes; my question is, [is changing the title case actually required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252687/1190388)?

Comment: My bigger concern is that the edits themselves aren't that great; you don't capitalize articles in titles unless it's the start of a sentence (like "The Little Prince" compared to "The Prince and the Pauper").  But, it looks like the question askers are actively *approving* these edits (from my skimming of them).  I don't think it helps much but I'd have to dig around a bit more to see any actual maliciousness here.

Comment: In fact, it should be discouraged. [Title Case is harder to read than Sentence case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280771/maximum-of-6-reviews-per-item-in-triage-queue).

Comment: Ironically, the title of this question is hard to read because of title case...

Comment: @DavidG It's the syntax, for me; not because of the case...

Answer (score 46):

Given that some of these edits even applied [the wrong capitalization for terms](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12499038), I'd say you're safe to reject most of them.

Converting a clearly written title into titlecase is unnecessary, and may in fact make the question harder to read. Question titles don't need to be titlecase, and usually aren't on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Not just wrong capitalization, but even changing spelling incorrectly ("PostGresSQL")

Comment: And banning reviewers should be a good way to teach that...

Answer (score 27):

A good question title will read like an actual question. For example, this question might legitimately have the title, "Should titles in questions be title case, and should we be editing them as such?"

Titles that read as questions should not have title case throughout, and since good questions have titles that read like questions, there shouldn't be much need for title case.

In any event, good suggested edits should be *substantial.*  While I Like Title Case as Much as the Next Person, changing titles to title case is not a good use of anyone's time.  I'd much rather suggested editors focus on problems like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time).

Comment: I agree, editors should be focusing on making substantial edits even if they only started editing the post for simpler reasons. [Thanks in advantage!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Answer (score 9):

Seeing how both sentence case and title case are about equally acceptable, I feel that it is comparable to switching brace style.

In other words, if it's the only thing that is changed, then it should be rejected as superfluous. You can reject and edit it yourself if you see other problems that you felt should be addressed.

Looking at this user's profile, they have been suggesting edits nonstop. The last SIX pages of their edit history are from the 24 hours alone.

Robo reviews suck. For shame people, for [shame](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12498698).