# What happens to "Should be improved" questions in the Triage queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

What happens to "Should be improved" questions in the [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) queue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right now, nothing because Triage is in a trial stage.  But if you go over to the announcement post you can see what the plan is for this.

[Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)

In that post, there is a flow chart of the whole process and this statement from **Shog9**:

> Behind the scenes, a "quality score" is calculated for each question based on an automated analysis of the content. Those that score well are sent immediately to the homepage; those that score poorly will now be sent to Triage. From there, they'll go to one of three places based on human input:
>
>  1. The homepage, where they can be answered
>  2. The close or moderator flag queue where they can be reviewed and eventually deleted
>  3. A new "Help and Improvement" queue where they can be edited

Comment: I'm looking forward to the Help and Improvement queue. What rep will be required to access it, do we know?