# Integrate an online UML/diagram editor such as Gliffy

Tags: feature-request

It is helpful to draw diagrams to illustrate a question or an answer. Since UML is the lingua franca of software descriptions, it'd be useful to be able to include such diagrams too. Right now the process is a bit cumbersome and requires the use of offline tools to grab screenshots to be transferred over to Imgur. It'd be neat if one could use an integrated tool from within a question or an answer.

Just as the [electrical engineering Stack Exchange site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) has integrated [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com), it'd help SE to integrate something like [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com) or a similar tool.

*I'm not affiliated with Gliffy or anyone else other than my wife and kids, for that matter.*

Comment: I've rarely seen any questions that can't do without UML diagrams. In those cases, if there _has_ to be a diagram, a screenshot of one works just as well. I don't see how the effort required to implement this would be worth it. For EE on the other hand, circuit diagrams are often crucial to explain what's (supposed to be) going on.

Comment: This probably wouldn't be a bad idea on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but you still already have the option of posting images there too.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm an EE, and I can trivially generate an isomorphic human-readable textual description for any circuit, so by that line of thinking why bother with circuit diagrams either? I mean, I just gave you a counterexample that works for *every* EE question: they **all** could do with a textual description only! I lament that the clarity and simplicity of circuit diagrams is *absent* from software and programming questions and answers. Having an integrated diagramming tool makes things easier, not harder.

Comment: This is, assuming everyone knows UML. Hobbyist programmers are less likely to know UML than hobbyist EE-ers are to know circuit diagrams. Those diagrams are like the API to your hardware, whipe UML is a tool you usually only learn about in school, or at your job.

Comment: Having people come to your desk and talk it through is generally better too. The point is whether the benefit to stack as a whole is worth the developer's time in implementing it? Or would that time be better spent on other projects.

Comment: @EBGreen: that's what I was trying to say, yea.

Comment: "Having people come to your desk and talk it through is generally better too." Thus the rubber ducky. It works just as well if you have to write it down nicely, and then you can add drawings too - if it's easy to do.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289817/add-flowchart-in-triage-review/289952#289952

Comment: Not to mention performance concerns. MathJax was turned down for this reason. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with this request.

I've rarely seen any questions that can't do without UML diagrams. In those cases, if there *has* to be a diagram, a **screenshot** of one works just as well. I don't see how the effort required to implement this would be worth it.

For EE on the other hand, circuit diagrams are often crucial to explain what's (supposed to be) going on.

Comment: It's true that you can do *without* UML. But I think that if we are to encourage judicious use of UML as a lingua franca, barriers to entry are unhelpful. Adoption of UML forces a clearer view of what's going on - whether you talk about class inheritance trees, or state transitions, or interactions. Sometimes just attempting to draw one immediately points out where the problem is. I'm as far from an enterprisey UML-everywhere proponent as it gets, but UML is a very concise and visual way of expressing quite a few things that are much harder to get across in writing, especially with ESL issues.

Comment: @KubaOber I don't think anyone's disagreeing that UML is a good thing, but you can do all that with gliffy and take a screenshot - what's the benefit of having the tool embedded in SO? Is it just to avoid that step of saving then uploading the image manually?

Comment: @Clive Whatever argument you have is the argument for not integrating CircuitLab into EE stackexchange, I think. The only benefit of the integration *there* is that you don't have to copy/upload images manually, and that the schematic is editable. Same would be here. And your argument would also apply to math stackexchange: we can all be copy-pasting screenshots from latex output...

Comment: Let's recap: Math SE has integrated their lingua franca: expressions, EE has integrated a circuit editor, SE & Programmers should imho integrate a diagram editor. Heck, probably *all* sites could use diagrams, so this could be site-wide. Taking apart the syntax of a sentence in some language that has its SE site? Use a diagram. Talking of some DIY gizmo? Draw it. And so on. The integration increases the likelihood of visual expression by an order of magnitude or more. IMHO we should be all for such integration.

Comment: I'm still not convinced. I just think the use case is way too small to justify implementing something this significant. Yout usage examples hardly apply to stack overflow. SO programming questions are mostly just bugs and simple logic that really doesn't need a diagram to explain.

Comment: Er, who's arguing? Chill, my friend. I just wanted clarification on your feature request, I'm not for or against it yet. Maybe linking to a few examples of great questions that could have been made even greater, or poor questions that could have been made good, by even including any UML at all, would help your case? Once that's established it'll be easier to talk about a problem that needs solving

Comment: Yeah, what @Cerbrus said. I mean, I do remember on occasion seeing a question and thinking "wouldn't mind seeing a class diagram for this", but it's not the norm in my own experience. Your experience is obviously different, so it would be interesting (for me anyway) to see the types of question that would routinely benefit from this feature

Answer (score 2):

Found this while thinking of requesting the same thing and I strongly agree with the suggestion.

It might be too difficult to integrate though, can't argue with that.

Now the standpoint from which I'm looking at this is not so much like, *"It's too hard to draw a diagram outside and upload a screenshot."*

I'm looking at it more like this:

> If we had this tool right out of the box, under our fingertips when typing answers
>   to a question, we might use it *more often*, leading to *higher-quality*
>   content all throughout the site. It might lead to more pearls which might have otherwise been duds.

I'm looking at it from the meta standpoint of trends and forecasts for human behavior (which is always how I'm looking at things). There are so many questions that benefit from a visual answer, whether it's a beginner question asking about what a piece of code does to a singly-linked list or whether it's an advanced design-related SE question.

While I agree with Cerberus' logic here:

> I've rarely seen any questions that can't do without UML diagrams.

... I recommend looking at it more like, *"How many questions could benefit from a visual answer? How many cases are there where an image might illustrate a concept better than a wall of text, e.g.?"*, and there's actually quite a large number of questions that could fit that category, especially when we're dealing with a beginner who still has a hard time even understanding pseudo-code. I taught CS long ago and it would have been hopeless without a whiteboard to draw on when a student asked me a question.

So my thoughts behind this kind of integrated feature is that it might start encouraging more and more people to often include visual diagrams in their answers. It might even save them time and effort while improving the quality of their answer to have this tool always available at their fingertips.

Again, since this feature wouldn't be implemented by me, I can't argue from a cost/reward perspective, not understanding the cost. But it definitely does seem to have a potential for a very high reward. A lesser form of this suggestion is just have a button in the editor that directly links to `gliffy`, e.g.

Comment: It's trivial to do using draw.io in embed mode, https://www.jgraph.com/so-example/Integrate%20an%20online%20UML_diagram%20editor%20such%20as%20gliffy%20-%20Meta%20Stack%20Overflow.html. Double click on the diagram to edit, then save in the editor to send it back. The details of the implementation are here https://support.draw.io/display/DO/2015/09/21/Simple+draw.io+embedding+walk-through.

Answer (score -7):

I am voting for diagram support - especially tools that follow the "diagram as code" idea.

---

I'm answering questions about [Apache NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-nifi). And it's a visual dataflow tool where we are talking about diagrams and not the code...

I am really missing a simple way to publish a diagram.

Currently I'm using [PlantUML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlantUML) as a way to publish a simple diagram. For example:
[Nifi - Dynamic attribute in the flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962538/nifi-dynamic-attribute-in-the-flow/75978676#75978676)

https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ENCODED-UML-DIAGRAM - URL to edit your diagram 
https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/ENCODED-UML-DIAGRAM - URL  publish your diagram

And to insert a diagram into your answer, the Markdown content looks like:

```
[![State diagram][1]][1]

  [1] https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/ENCODED-UML-DIAGRAM
```