# What happens to questions reviewed as "requires editing"?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

What happens to a question reviewed in Triage as 'requires editing'?

Where does it land, or how does one see that the question needs to be edited?

Comment: It lands in the Help and Improvement queue

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280815/what-happens-to-should-be-improved-questions-in-the-triage-queue)

Comment: Is that a public queue? Where is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/helper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They end up in the [Help & Improvement review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper), as you can read in the introductory post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466/4751173):

> A short time ago, we introduced the new triage queue - a place where users can quickly sort questions into various categories, where one of those categories is 'needs improvement'.
>
> ...
>
> Today, we're happy to announce that this queue is now accessible, in a much earlier state than planned.
>
> If you've got at least 2000 rep, please go say hello to The Help & Improvement Queue!

The <kbd>Needs improvement</kbd> has been replaced by <kbd>Requires editing</kbd>, but the process is still the same. There is an interesting flowchart involving the Triage and Help & Improvement review queues in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323945/4751173):

> [image: flowchart]

Comment: @rene thanks - I knew that diagram but couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: Neither could I and I was pressured by a [mod](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32111101#32111101) to find it ...

Comment: The 2000 rep requirement explains why I couldn't find it. Thanks, I learn a little bit every day! :)