# Policy enforcement on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I am an avid user and amateur contributor to many of the Stack Exchange websites, including Stack Overflow and a few others.  I have noticed in particular on Stack Overflow that newbies seem to come on the site from nowhere and post questions that aren't worded clearly or are only partially thought out.  Part of this may be due to that they are unfamiliar with the site.  The other part may be that they themselves don't fully understand what they are doing, hence a poorly structured question.

Toward fixing this problem, could Stack Overflow moderators take the following step:

1. Ask all new users (users who have not earned a certain threshold reputation) to first check the Stack Overflow database questions which may already answer the question.
2. Ask all new users to double check their question before submitting it.  New users don't necessarily have to be blocked, but a simple dialog box reminding them to review could go a long way.
3. Stack Overflow moderators should closely monitor such newbie questions, and edit/remove them if they are duplicate or not worded in such a way that the question can be answered.

Bullet point #2 is particularly important for Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), because it would help to prevent the database from being cluttered with redundancies.  And once a question is in the system, it will be much harder to argue removing it later on.

Comment: 1. already done. 2. click `next`. 3. moderators have better things to do, there is a first post queue. That is sufficient.

Comment: Why was this question voted down 8 times?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. All new users are given a [*before you ask* screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) with guidance and a search box, and are asked to search first. There is a checkbox on that page you need to tick before you can continue. We cannot *force* users to read it, many don't.
2. Users that didn't read the screen with the tickbox, won't read advice on how to re-check their question. We already lost those users. For those that do read, the *Ask a Question* page links to [further advice on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); that page includes a section on proofreading your post.
3. Moderators cannot monitor the flood of questions. The community can, and does monitor new questions, **all the time**. New user questions are also automatically filed into several review queues based on criteria, such as the new [triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) and the [*First Post*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) and [*Late Answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) queues.

It is actually quite easy to remove redundancies; if a question is a duplicate, people with a *gold tag badge* in the tags used on the post can [close the question as a duplicate with just one vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). We call it dupe hammering. Apart from that it only takes 5 users with the [close and reopen privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to vote to close a post; there is another [review queue to help out with that](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats); users with less than 3k points can flag for closure instead and those posts go to the queue as well.

Comment: How do I obtain such a gold badge?  Many of the responses I give are in the comments section referring to other SO articles which the author neglected to read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: if you have answered at least 200 questions in a tag, and your total answer score for that tag is 1000 or over, you are given the badge. Score is the net vote count on your posts, so upvotes minus downvotes. See the [*Badges* tab](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (scroll down to the *Tag badges* section).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: if you look at my [Meta profile badges tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=badges&sort=class) you'll see I have a few light-grey badges with gold circle. Those are gold tag badges. My [Stack Overflow profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=badges&sort=class) has a few more.

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely right that many of the typical problems with questions from new users stem from the fact that SE is different from typical BB style forums, and they are unfamiliar with how it works. But the system already does the things you recommend.

Numbers 1 and 2 are taken care of by a number of reminders on the ask question page: two different windows showing questions which are similar / may already have an answer, a modal reminder on submit (Perhaps only for unregistered users? Not positive about this), etc. There's also the explanations in the tour and help centers.

The problem is that the traffic on SO is *huge*; some duplicates, clueless users and bad questions are inevitable. A balance must be struck between prodding users to research their question first and making it not obnoxious to post questions. There are plenty of post-posting checks in place, so the system doesn't need to nag so much before hand. Would you want to use a site that forces you to click a bunch of "yes I already searched for this" buttons before asking your question? I wouldn't.

Number 3 is covered by the review queues, which are currently undergoing a major improvement. Remember that the moderators here are *all users*. And generally the community does a great job of keeping on top of things.

Answer (score 2):

We already have a [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that asks every new user posting their first question the first two points. If a new user chooses to ignore that advice, there's not much more that can be done.

As for the third point, that's not our job either. The community already does this on its own volition through the numerous [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: fair enough.  Though I can tell you that every morning I spend about 45 minutes on my train ride to the office going through new questions on Stack Overflow and there is A LOT of garbage being posted.  I hope this stuff all gets voted down so the integrity of the database can be maintained.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: There is a lot of garbage, but I have faith that the community will keep it in check... for now.