# How do you even find questions to answer?

Tags: discussion

This may be an unpopular opinion, but SO is such a mess.

I go to the front page, look through the questions. Every question already has an answer or is down-voted to oblivion. I try visiting the "unanswered" page (under "newest"), I refresh for an hour, looking through questions I don't care about... Until *suddenly*... A question with my tags!

Oh wait, it's a question about using the MellonicJuiceHippityScardoJS extension. I'm not familiar with that. Guess I can't answer that.

Now let me try clicking on my tags, under "newest" (for instance, 'PHP').

Question 1 - "hallo how do u do dis 2 me pliz do my hw" Skip.

Question 2 - *About to answer*... Nope, someone already answered. Sadness intensifies.

Question 3 - This isn't even a PHP question...

Question 4 - **Another question about BrownieCakeCinammonBunPHP extension**. **STOP.**

*REFRESH*

Same exact thing pops out.

I feel like SO is too hard to navigate. From experience, this design works well in Math SE because there are very few questions asked in a given period of time, but obviously not for SO that gets about 8 (?) questions per second. There needs to be a change to the website's format or some features need to be added to make navigation easier. I'd say adding/enforcing a `framework-specific` tag is a good start, but the overall organization of the website needs to be changed. SO has become too big to easily answer questions on, and more features for finding questions to answer should be added.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I looked at that already, I'm not asking the same thing.

Comment: The could you clarify what you *are* asking, please? It's also helpful to mention what you've already seen, and how precisely it has failed to address your issue.

Comment: I fail to see how this is not a duplicate. The other post outlines how people (including me) find questions to answer. *That's the advice we can give you*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not looking for advice; I'm calling for a change in the format of SO. I looked at your advice before writing this. An apple is not a "possible duplicate" of an orange.

Comment: Then *improve your question*, because that's not clear to me. Your title seems to conflict with your comments.

Comment: *"I'd say adding/enforcing a `framework-specific` tag is a good start"* - how do you see this working? How would it be enforced? What about questions that aren't related to frameworks? *"the overall organization of the website needs to be changed"* - how? *"more features for finding questions to answer should be added"* - do you have any specific ideas or goals? What do you think would be helpful, and what are your criteria for determining whether any changes have been successful? As it stands, this is just a complaint (not even a particularly specific one) and not terribly constructive.

Comment: You can see from my profile that I do not have any problems finding questions to answer. Have you tried to use my method at all? You can add tags to your 'ignore' and 'favorite' lists to highlight or dim (or even hide) specific tags in the list. And *stop refreshing* the pages. Let the live-load feature bring you the questions as they come in.

Comment: You seem to mostly complain about how new questions are not tagged properly. That's being addressed with the new [triage review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) and other [Stack Exchange quality project efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project).