# Why in triage queue unsalvageable questions get flagged instead of voted to close

Tags: support, triage

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), but I still don't understand how this is supposed to work. When I click the unsalvagable button, I get the flagging interface which has "it should be closed" option, and then it looks like I'm flagging with one of the standard close reasons. Why can't I simply vote to close when I click unsalvageable? Am I supposed to spend my "flags remaining" on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry: flags for closure are automatically converted to close votes for users with close-voting privileges without using up your daily flag allowance.

Presumably the flagging interface is used instead in order to consolidate the close reasons with other flag options, since clicking the Unsalvageable option immediately brings up a modal dialog.