# Is it okay to ask a question "draft" and then afterwards edit it?

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask a question which is just the plain question itself, which might even contain some bad typo or grammar and then immediately start to edit it to make it "beatiful"?

I often think something like

> That would be a question I should put on stackoverflow.

So I just take everything I already found, including links and then just throw them into one ugly question.

Ugly in the means of:

- quick and dirty (more dirty than quick) text including above mentioned mistakes
- a list of links which might not even be in a bullet list
- thrown in code pieces
- minimal structure (first the text, then code, then links)
- no highlighting

Then I post it as a question hit edit and start to add a better text, some kind of highlighting and put in some structure. Lastly some comments for the code.

This gives me the opportunity of not wasting time (the community might be able to answer the question even if it looks awful so I get the answers earlier) and the community can edit the question too and earn reputation.

I don't know if this is allowed explicitly, but that is why I ask you.
Is it?

Comment: All it does is create unnecessary editing work for the community.  There are already plenty of posts that need our attention; why knowingly create more?

Comment: I notice this question has acquired downvotes. Please think twice before doing so--this is a very good issue to address.

Comment: You can, and I can downvote it and vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: If you want downvotes and closure of the question, sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no *rule* against this, but it's not a good idea. You are risking getting a few downvotes in the first few minutes the question is visible. Users who see the question in its draft form and navigate away may also not revisit it later.

In the future, posting a question that is poor in its first revision [may send it to an improvement queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/2891664) instead of the regular homepage. This somewhat defeats your original purpose of saving time.

Whether it's a serious *detraction* or a *waste of a viewer's time* depends on how bad the state of the draft is, but the important thing is that you want all of the views to count.

Comment: I would like to let you know that your answer is in my opinion the most matching for my question as yours does mention the improvement queue, which is for sure useful for people new on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 14):

No, you should be spending the effort constructing your question into as good of a question as you're able to do before posting it.  It is *extremely* inconsiderate to post a question that you know is of low quality, and that you could fix up, in the hopes that other people will simply do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to define the line as to how low quality a post can be before it's off-topic, so the answer to this question depends what you mean by "OK".

Clearly, you're allowed to edit a question to make it better after it's been posted. It isn't expected that every question is going to be in perfect form immediately when it's posted. But I think most of the people here would agree with me when I say that it would be best practice that if you know beforehand that a post needs major editing before it's going to be a "good" question, **edit first**, *then* post.

If you know your post isn't in the form you'd want to read it in, don't expect anyone else to want to read it that way either. This is better for you too because you're much less likely to get a negative reception (i.e. downvotes or closure) to a question you've spent some time on rather than just dumping your thoughts and expecting others to detangle them.