# Triage: Add explanation what's the reason for having a triage at all

Tags: feature-request, triage

Right now, there is almost zero explanation about what the "Triage" is and why it makes sense. On the triage page itself it just says

> Help identify the quality of questions

and

> We need your help separating questions into categories.

Please include (a link to) an explanation like that: [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)

Comment: Isn't this how community closes posts?

Comment: Possibly related: [Our words are too complicated. Let's make them simpler!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler)

Comment: It doesn't really do much given that Unsalvageable doesn't actually hide questions. Hopefully when it is more developed a concrete purpose will be easy to communicate to reviewers.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage