# How does Triage determine the consensus?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I've started doing some Reviews in the Triage queue lately, and I wanted to go back to look at some (particularly when the flag I raised in it came back as disputed). I've noticed some where the result is "The consensus is: this post Looks OK.", but to my untrained eye I see several people agreeing with me that it isn't okay. For example, [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12495607) where there are 3 "Looks OK", 2 "Requires Editing", and 2 "Unsalvageable". That's four people saying it isn't OK, and 3 people saying it is, but the system seems to call that a "Consensus" because it hit 3 "Looks OK" votes? Is that all that it looks for, or is the system more complicated than that?

Is this an example of the system (1) a problem, (2) working fine, (3) not working but the results of Triage aren't that critical so it doesn't really matter, or (4) something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 2: a Triage review can have 3 outcomes, and the first option which gets 3 'votes' is chosen and finishes the review.

(source: 3k Triage reviews by yours truly; it's hard to to find an *offical* source - it's neither [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) nor [there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue))

And you were right, this type of questions is too broad for Stack Overflow.