# Shouldn't 2 Unsalvageable + 2 Requires Editing be more than 3 Looks Ok?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage

I have started reviewing questions, and I am reviewing the outcomes, to improve my reviews and to see what other people think. I read [How does Triage determine the consensus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323940/how-does-triage-determine-the-consensus) and get the 3-votes win. However, I don't understand why a question that has, for example 2 *Unsalvageable*, 2 *Requires Editing*, and 3 *Looks OK* votes leads to:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post Looks OK.

Clearly, 4 out of 7 people think that the post needs work or should be closed. I don't think the consensus is that it *Looks OK*.

IMHO, there should be at least one more *Looks OK* vote to have "consensus" in Triage of questions like this. I would say the same if there were 2 *Looks OK* and 3 *Unsalvageable* or 3 *Requires Editing* as well.

I have voted for *Requires Editing* on questions that are marginal to being flagged to close and am much more likely to do so when I have run out of "flag credits". Maybe I should just skip those? What is the thought on reviewing a question where it should be flagged to close and you do not have enough flags left to do so?

Maybe the results of the Triage isn't that critical? In which case I'm not going to waste time with it.

Comment: Meh, I wanted absolute majority instead of simple.

Comment: First-past-the-post voting strikes again!

Answer (score 20):

This is an issue of perspective. You're seeing it as:

a) **Unsalvageable** - Doesn't look OK

b) **Requires Editing** - Doesn't look OK

c) **Looks OK**

But you could equally see it as:

a) **Unsalvageable**

b) **Requires Editing** - Not Unsalvageable

c) **Looks OK** - Not Unsalvageable

or even:

a) **Unsalvageable** - Requires no editing

b) **Requires Editing**

c) **Looks OK** - Requires no editing

This is the same issue that takes place with first-past-the-post elections, and nobody's yet come up with a solution that everybody likes.

But in this case we have an obvious scale from **Unsalvageable** to **Looks OK**, so we can assume people's second choice would be **Requires Editing** if they didn't choose that in the first place; I suggest the following variant of STV:

- Once any option has reached 3 votes, it is examined.
- If that option is **Requires Editing**, then that is the result.
- If it isn't, the value of 2/3 of the third option is added to the **Required Editing** votes, and the winner chosen.
- If there's a tie, **Requires Editing** wins.

This solution means that 1/2/3 would be a win for **Looks OK**, whereas 2/2/3 would be a win for **Requires Editing**.

Comment: Actually "Looks OK" means "Others can see this and their eyes are likely to not bleed"... guess whose eyes are bleeding?

Comment: "You could equally see it as... **Looks OK** - Salvageable". Er.....I really don't think that would be a good way to read that option.

Comment: @KyleStrand I think the terminology is off, but the point is correct.  Replace the word **Salvageable** with **Doesn't need to be removed**, or something.  The point is that for every possible pairing of two-out-of-three of the options, there exists a shared property that isn't in the third.

Comment: @Ironcache Indeed, I've adjusted appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Well, at the moment it's first option chosen three times wins.

That's probably not *too bad* for "requires editing", but the other two options should only win when more than half of votes are for them, in order to avoid the absurd outcome of "looks ok" or "unsalvagable" when that's a mis-representation of the consensus.