# Remind users to check web console before submitting JavaScript questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Whenever someone posts a problem involving JavaScript, one of the first questions we almost always ask is whether there are any errors in the JavaScript console. Could we prompt them to check this and include the information in the question, whenever the question is tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)?

I'm not expecting that if they do this they'll be able to solve the problem themselves (although if they can, that would be great -- it's probably simple enough that it wouldn't be a useful SO question). If they aren't experienced enough to know to check the console, they probably won't understand the error messages, either. But it will make the question more complete before we start trying to answer it. Currently we have to waste time dragging additional information out of the OP.

Comment: If something like this were implemented, I would appreciate a cut-off, perhaps based on how much rep a user has in a JavaScript or related tag. No need to harass the experts.

Comment: That's certainly reasonable. Whatever the usual policy for displaying reminders is fine.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - I was thinking about a different cut-off, so not to confuse newbies, who never heard of Dev Tools and just want to find out how to populate an array with random numbers.

Comment: @PM77-1 The newbies are the ones who need to be informed about things like Dev Tools. If this can be automated during the question-writing process, is it really better to let them submit the question and then have to deal with "Have you checked for errors in the Javascript console" comments?

Comment: I agree with @torazaburo. I would've not commented if I saw [his answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325623/2055998) beforehand.

Comment: What if it's server-side javascript and there is no console?

Comment: @Houseman Then the reminder doesn't apply to them. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar If the user is in Node.js ,one could either be mislead and end up being more confused, searching for something that doesn't exist. Also, being improperly pestered about something that doesn't apply to them seems like a problem in itself.

Comment: @Houseman Good point. Perhaps the code is running in an interplanetary probe past Pluto, and the log data will to take six hours to get here. Seriously, node **does** have a console, and not knowing what it is and how to access it is precisely analogous, and equally disqualifying, to not knowing how to view the browser console. In general, your attitude accounts for a large part of the reason why no proposal ever gets off the ground. Can't you think of some way to solve the problem, instead of coming up with lame reasons why someone else's well-meaning solution (upvoted 50 times) won't work?

Comment: @Houseman If you want, we could use more generic terms like "Please include include error messages", but then you end up confusing the 99% who are using a browser and don't know where to look for them because the reminder was too vague. We could add a link with more details that say where to look in each browser and Node.js, but do you really think they'll click on it? Let's not let the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Amend that to be _"rep a user has in javascript answers"_ and I'm all for it.

Comment: Maybe if they have a quote that "looks like" an error message, it does not alert them

Answer (score 128):

In the true meta spirit of pissing on all proposals, no matter how potentially helpful, for reasons ranging from something similar was proposed before and somebody didn’t like it, or I’m in a bad mood, or it won’t solve all our problems so we shouldn’t even think about it any more, or it violates some written or unwritten philosophical precept of SO, or it has the theoretical potential to be abused in some contorted hypothetical scenario, let me say that your proposed warning is a very small finger in a very large dike with a very large number of holes.

The problem in the majority of the cases is **not** that the OP does not look at the console, it is that **they don't even know what the console is**. Their ignorance of the console is part of a larger pattern of ignorance, lack of curiosity, refusal to read the most basic documentation or tutorials, lack of comprehension of basic debugging techniques, and frankly pure laziness, all of which is what is behind their posts in the first place. For them, saying in a warning "please view console errors before posting" is the rough equivalent of saying "please frobnicate the thingamajig before posting". Are we also going to add to the warning that they should lint their code, and that they should try to, uhh, debug their code? What is the motivation for them to spend half an hour finding the problem themselves, when they can post in 30 seconds and get three answers pointing out their typo 30 seconds after that?

If we do add more suggestions about things for them to do before posting, at that point, the warning will essentially turn into a tutorial on how to find problems in your JS code. Or, we could point them to a canonical answer on standard ways to do that, yet a proposal to do exactly that was rejected as being "too broad" and/or being a "list-type question". Or we could wait for Documentation, and hope and pray that someone actually bothers to write something on this topic, but what's the point? Why would these newbies suddenly start reading some documentation here when they don't read any of the other documentation which is out there?

I personally believe the best but not only (we need an "all-of-the-above" approach here) solution to the cancer of "my code doesn't work" questions is to close them as quickly and simply as possible, most likely by giving more close powers to people who know the tag. We've been over this territory ad nauseum. These proposals are invariable shot down by naysayers whining that for every 100 questions justifiably closed, one question might be closed in error, hurting some poor user's feelings, and that the mechanisms for re-opening and flagging inexplicably won't work, or that some rogue high-rep user might go berserk and start closing everything in sight and there would be no way to stop him or her.

The meta question, which I have no hope will ever be solved, is how the community can coalesce around simple, reasonable steps with good potential for solving the problem, without every suggestion or initiative being shot down by snipers.

Comment: I've been doing this long enough that I don't have any illusions that this will make a huge difference. I just thought it could be a simple change that might help a few posters. Maybe as a future project a checklist of basic troubleshooting steps might be useful (e.g. for 500 errors, check the server log, for C/C++ errors, run the program under a debugger).

Comment: @Barmar you should start with "For solving a problem, search and read. Before asking, read some more. After asking, read."

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yeah, I'd really like it to say "First learn how to program". :)

Comment: You're my Douchbag-Fanboy of the month @trazaburo! But know that: I'll strip you of your title in a heartbeat if you take offense at this statement. Don't ever change. 

Also - "a very small finger in a very large dike with a very large number of holes" - I can't wait to use this in a conversation.

Comment: lool! I like the first paragraph.

Comment: hmm one of the problems I have as a beginner is, that I'm willing to search - and do so for hours, but am unable to find the right query/search terms. A friend types one word and finds the solution in 5s. Often enough a short hint in the right direction helps. Maybe thats another cause for the problem.

Comment: @Rhayene That's a good point, but the topic here is not searching for answers, but rather questions with real simple typos and syntax errors. You can't search for the solution to that. You have to develop the skills to find them.

Comment: @torazaburo I meant something in the lines of the ternary operator in java - I didn't find anything without the word ternary (": operator java" didn't work at all for me) - I wasn't able to fix a bug in code given to me, because I didn't know how it looked right - was a simple syntax error - but still

Comment: A man after my heart! *"Or we could wait for Documentation, and hope and pray..., but what's the point?"* Indeed. *"solution to the cancer of "my code doesn't work" questions is to close them as quickly and simply as possible, most likely by giving more close powers to people who know the tag."* Yes, I couldn't agree more. I don't really know who is against this, other than the people who want to ask these types of questions. Then again, these same people don't agree that there is actually a problem, so they aren't looking for a solution. You don't ask the tumor how it wants to be treated.

Comment: @Cody _"I don't really know who is against this, other than the people who want to ask these types of questions"_ - the people who want to answer them, and the people who think that every question is a good question, because it might help one person.

Comment: Yeah, people who think we should give out participation ribbons to everyone at science fairs. Because every question is special and created equal. If those people cherish the freedom to ask any damned old thing so much, why are they here instead of Yahoo! Answers?

Comment: One thing: whether you think that someone who gets "hurt feelings" by their experience here is being reasonable or not, if enough people walk away thinking "SO is a bunch of jerks", then that's the message they take out into the world, justified or not. As I read through this post, I agreed with it, but I am worried about a sort of sneering indifference that seems to wax and wane around here. Remember to be awesome.

Comment: Totally agree and this: "get three answers pointing out their typo 30 seconds after that" is a big part of the problem. Answerers should know better than to reward low effort posts but they're just trying to grab the points. I'll vote to close a bad question and then see that two users with >4000 rep have answered with the [typo|misunderstanding of basic language syntax|etc]. The site has a cancer, and many of our - high rep - users are throwing the site into a tanning bed every day.

Comment: While we're at it we might as well add a prompt for IT problems: "1. Is it plugged in? 2. Have you tried turning it off and on again? "

Comment: Would it become a downvotable offense for someone to ask a question about JavaScript in Safari for iOS while explaining that he [lacks a suitably recent Mac on which to show the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587063/ios-6-debug-console-gone)?

Comment: Just created a "Debugging" topic in Documentation for JavaScript. Your prayers have been heard.

Comment: @DawnPaladin  one think is that "you can't" and another totally different is that you didn't even tried. At this point of time, anyone that finds a problem with Safari mobile should have at least some interactions with any desktop version and used the console there (and then curse at Apple for denying such a tool in their mobile version).

Comment: @DamianYerrick can you use different names :( The comment above was intended for you.

Answer (score 2):

As a newbie here, who has just asked one of these questions ([Custom .toString() method on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820979/custom-tostring-method-on-an-array)), I wanted to suggest two things that may have prevented me from degrading average post quality while still helping me get to the answer to my question:

1. On JavaScript questions in particular, include a link to a jshint.com and/or other linters. In my case above, however, it actually would not have helped since no jshint gives no warning in my case and jslint broadly warns on `this`.

   There were several cases where I've posted or drafted questions here that a linter would have diagnosed. I've never had Google suggest a linter over SO for any of my newbie questions.

   This could just be the top suggested link and/or a checkbox that appears for those under a certain rep.
2. At the risk of derailing this question, I'd ask whether new users could be routed into something of a training ground. Their 'questions' don't actually become such until approved. Prior to that time, they reside in something closer to the 'chat' state -- visible only to members and NOT indexed by the site search functionality. Only if the question gets approved are rep points earned.

   Finally, if the 'question' is in fact a duplicate, it could just get added, visibly or invisibly, for search purposes to the authoritative question if not already covered. Newbs would then be adding value to the site in terms of indexing, instead of watering down its value with duplicative questions.

---

(While this may be too narrow a case, if the suggested links had recognized that I was writing JS and saw a "=>", it could have included the term "fat arrow" or "arrow function" in the search terms since I didn't realize it was relevant.)

Comment: For #2, this has been suggested many times on Meta. Honestly, new users should be 1) searching and researching on their own and 2) reading the help center and taking the [tour], before asking questions at all. We also have [the Triage queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/215552) which is similar to what your suggesting. Duplicates are kept on the site already for search puproses.

Comment: I think the last suggestion is far too AI for the automated suggester to handle. How should it know that a question that contains `=>` is actually a problem related to understanding arrow functions? You could be using it properly, and the problem is totally unrelated. Or you could have PHP code mixed in with your Javascript, and `=>` is part of the PHP associative array syntax.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just saying if a question has a [javascript] tag and the characters `=>` inside any code block, add the term 'arrow function' to the terms used to generate the suggested links.  It might be hard to implement even though easy to describe depending on how search terms are currently derived, but it's not really AI.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Three conflicting interests to optimize: SEO, user acquisition/ retention and question quality. Over- (or under-) maximizing one harms the other two. Is that what it comes down to?

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment relates to mine...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan probably just related to the different perspectives we have on the topic at hand. Yours comes from a place of significantly more legitimacy. Mine from naivete of a new user and thus I was basically withdrawing from the debate by acknowledging that the bigger picture is basically impossible for someone in my position to fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @torazaburo answer - it may be hard for an experienced programmer to imagine, but checking the console for a newbie may not be helpful at all! If they checked console, the only difference would be that instead of a "my code doesn't work" question, we'd get a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: x" question. I mean, I even remember it myself when I was a beginner, errors in console where for me just a nuisance and I didn't even know what they meant. Like in the above example - a newbie after reading will just scratch his head and think "What the hell is a reference? Variable, variable... it rings a bell, but... nope, no idea what that is."

So like @torazaburo I think it's just a part of a much bigger problem, which is people who don't know the very basics of programming and googling.

Comment: If they don't even know what a variable is when *programming*, maybe SO is not the tool they need, but some course or tutorial.

Comment: @Blackus: exactly, and that's the problem.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. We **want** the question to include the error message they got, as that's what we need to be able to answer it. I think you may be misunderstanding the point of my suggestion: it's not to get them to fix the problem themselves (although that could happen), it's to make the question more complete, so we don't waste time asking lots of questions to get all the details.

Comment: @Barmar Ah yes you're right, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Dunno I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @barmar    we don't need crappy questions to be more answerable. We need them to be closed faster.

Comment: @JanDvorak How do you know it's a crappy question until you read it? Do you just assume that any question from someone who doesn't know to look for errors in the console will be crappy?