# Request: Canonical question about not throwing away exception details

Tags: discussion, canonical

Quite often I stumble upon code which uses exception handling incorrectly; in particular, which **throws away exception details**. Examples:

```
// Example 1: swallow exception
catch (Exception ex) {}

// Example 2: replace helpful message with unhelpful one
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred!!!11");
}

// Example 3: abuse catch as finally without re-throwing
try
{
    ...
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

I'm sure you all have seen even more variants of this theme.

Is there a canonical question which explains why this is evil and will make debugging a nightmare? If not, does anyone want to write one? (In fact, since SO Documentation is available now, would a documentation entry on this topic be appropriate?)

Comment: This is the basic reason why Docs will never be a substitute for Q+A.  Programmers write this kind of code because they don't understand the exception message and therefore assume that his user won't understand it either.  Inevitably MessageBox.Show() doesn't make it more understandable so next stop is SO.  Without the exception details of course.  What they didn't think to do is google the exception message.  Or did but were unable to apply the advice.  No docs or canonical Q+A is going to fix that.

Comment: Related somehow http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325614/remind-users-to-check-web-console-before-submitting-javascript-questions

Comment: And the incentive to write a good canonical answer is potentially 500 rep from [Madara](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254137/enhance-moderation-ability-by-encouraging-excellent-content).

Comment: Do we get questions that could be closed as duplicates of this canonical question? Whenever I see bad exception handling in SO questions, it's just there in the OP's code - they're not asking about it, it's incidental. I suppose we can still link it in comments..

Comment: There's also bad practices that are language specific, for example in C# `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } // whoops`. I think it may balloon.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It's like the [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) question -- instead of closing as unclear, we can close as a duplicate of a question that will help the asker improve their question.

Comment: Also, if someone does write this, try to write it in a way that doesn't result in the follow-up question being closed as a duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).  That probably involves linking to it, but you also have to convince them that actually reading the stack trace will let them solve their own problem without waiting for another answer.