# Is this an appropriate stock comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

There's a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) who posts the following stock comment in practically every C/C++ question he sees:

> The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)]](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) At least leave us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96)™)

Most of the people posting these questions are newbies who need lots of hand-holding to figure out what their problem is. Just telling them to use their debugger seems unhelpful. Some of the questions aren't even about debugging, they're "how do I do X" questions.

And sometimes they *have* provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that part of his comment is just plain wrong. E.g. [skipping over my last cin input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058312/skipping-over-my-last-cin-input).

I've asked him not to post this comment when it's inappropriate, but he just keeps on doing it. He says he uses this stock comment because he's gotten tired of posting more specific comments, but is that really a valid excuse?

Is the idea expressed in his comment appropriate? If not, what can be done about his serial commenting?

BTW, I'm similarly annoyed by JavaScript questions where the OP obviously didn't check the web console for errors. I posted [Remind users to check web console before submitting JavaScript questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325614/remind-users-to-check-web-console-before-submitting-javascript-questions) a few months ago, and the answers seemed to have more sympathy for the clueless posters. So web programmers aren't expected to know how to use the basic debugging tools before posting, but C/C++ programmers are?

Comment: `Most of the people posting these questions are newbies who need lots of hand-holding to figure out what their problem is.` agreed - but are those really our audience? It's the eternal Culture War of Stack Overflow. I can't help but agree that the comment sounds like the minimal standard we should hold people to and that SO would be a much better place if that was generally understood.

Comment: Well, it seems like the majority of the questions that tend to be asked on SO would then be ruled out.

Comment: Yup, and it might be a much better place for it...

Comment: I admit that when I first joined SO, I expected it to be experienced programmers helping other experienced programmers with tricky problems (I came here because I had such a problem). But as far as I can tell, it's mostly experienced programmers teaching beginners.

Comment: That's probably the reality, yes. But then there's nothing wrong with teaching even beginners basic standards and some amount of self-sufficiency in problem solving. It worked for earlier generations, it's gonna work for today's young folk

Comment: While I agree with @Pekka웃 that we can do without the many low quality questions, I agree with you that comments should be appropriate to the post being commented on. I a user doesn't have the time to customise a stock comment to fit the post, it would be better not to comment.

Comment: @Pekka웃 "It's the eternal Culture War of Stack Overflow." there's no culture war at SO, just users that know how to make a successful site and others that don't care. The real question is what each user believe themself to be, and what they real are.

Comment: I think the comment was appropriate for the linked question.  It wasn't an answer, but it could give a newbie a nudge toward finding their own answer.   Why not take advantage of a common, teachable moment with a stock comment?  If it was being spammed indiscriminantly on irrelevant questions,  it would be another story, but that's not what I'm seeing here.

Comment: @JimLewis The OP did provide a MCVE, so that part of the comment was inappropriate. I'm also not sure how running it under the debugger would have helped, either. Where would the debugger have told him that `cin >> gnp_florida` failed because he typed inappropriate input?

Comment: @Barmar _"The OP did provide a MCVE"_ The comment says _**at least**_ for this should be a problem.

Comment: Are you a native English speaker? "At least do X" implies that they didn't do X. Also, it means that providing an MCVE is sufficient, although additional information would be better.

Comment: @Barmar _"Are you a native English speaker?"_ No I'm not, but usually I can communicate in english very well and clear. Though google translate gives me the [exact meaning of what I used there](https://translate.google.de/#en/de/at%20least). I'd expect that as a minimum effort put in.

Comment: Google Translage doesn't understand nuances and context. "At least" can be used in a number of different ways.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have a better (more clear) suggestion? I'm open to adopt it if so. (_"Translage "_ You're off by one row at your keyboard?)

Comment: Instead of "At least" you should say "Also". But you should edit this line out if they did provide an MCVE. I also think you're being too critical if the MCVE isn't perfect (e.g. the one where they forgot to copy a function that it called). Remember, the whole reason they're here is that they don't know what they're doing!

Comment: BTW, I'm similarly annoyed by Javascript questions where the OP obviously didn't check the web console for errors. I asked [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325614/remind-users-to-check-web-console-before-submitting-javascript-questions) a few months ago, and the answers seemed to have more sympathy for the clueless posters.

Comment: @Barmar _"BTW, I'm similarly annoyed by Javascript questions where the OP obviously didn't check the web console "_ So why don't you create a stock comment for this?

Comment: I think that response will often depend on who sees the post, and sometimes even what mood they're in, subjective yes, but we're all human. Myself, I can forgive ignorance since we're all born ignorant, but not lack of some modicum of effort.

Comment: @Barmar You're probably just envious about my ™ ;)

Comment: I don't need to automate "What do you see in the Javascript console?"

Comment: @Barmar There's no more _automation_ rather than writing the text. Where I'm applying that is cherry picked as mentioned.

Comment: But I only post that for questions where I suspect that there actually would have been errors, or where those errors would help me answer the question.

Comment: @Barmar What's your experience with c++ actually?

Comment: Not much in practice. But I don't see how that matters, since your stock comment is language-agnostic. But I have over 35 years of experience programming in general, and I'm fluent in about a dozen different programming languages of all styles.

Comment: @Barmar My programming experience for c++ is similar than your time being in the business. I'm able to spot where that kinda stuff applies or not, and I'm solely acting at that tag mostly.

Comment: *"I've asked him not to post this comment when it's inappropriate, but he just keeps on doing it"* - then this is probably just a difference of opinion over when is appropriate to post it.

Comment: Maybe there should be more examples of the comment being misused (not being helpful). I just googled some of its occurences and I felt like it isn't deliberately being misused (however also not being extremely helpful).

Comment: _"I also think you're being too critical if the MCVE isn't perfect (e.g. the one where they forgot to copy a function that it called)."_ A MCVE that doesn't contain a function that was called is not an MCVE, and posting one indicates that the OP didn't test the MCVE. That's a **critical failure** for a question, not a minor infraction to be ignored.

Comment: _"Remember, the whole reason they're here is that they don't know what they're doing!"_ Right, and this stock comment serves to teach them precisely that. There's no point in enabling ignorance when you can instead correct it!

Comment: His stock comment doesn't really teach them much. I looked at the Eric Lippert page he links to (which we also link to in the help pages). If I were a beginner, my head would be spinning after trying to read that, it's too much to take in at once. When it gets to the point of recommending that they use a debugger, it doesn't explain *how* to use the debugger. So if you don't already know, you're stuck.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "...Right, and this stock comment serves to teach them precisely that...." That's the crucial question, isn't it. How much does it actually teach? I guess with more time one could actually give better and more specialized advice but the time might just not be available. And maybe the comment can also be further optimized. I would shorten it a bit.

Comment: @Barmar: _"When it gets to the point of recommending that they use a debugger, it doesn't explain how to use the debugger. So if you don't already know, you're stuck"_ Yes far be it for us to suggest that they perform some research on the subject and _find out_. They're not "stuck" at all if they put some time and thought into it, like the rest of us do.

Comment: So we're basically saying that all the people who start their question with "I just started programming yesterday" should stay away. Come back after you've spent a few months studying.

Comment: @Barmar Of course not. It's just a comment (even just a stock comment) and not the official line. No need to make more of it than what it's worth. If you ask me: People who started progamming yesterday should find help here, but the right kind of help, mostly helping them to help themselves. Using a debugger knowledge is essential. What we may need are more links to better tutorials maybe and the right kind of balance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Research mostly means avoiding duplicates or that simple googling gives already the answer. Full knowledge of a debugger might not fall in this category (and minimal understanding also) or maybe it should? Could be another discussion.

Comment: @Trilarion: Research goes _far_ beyond a single Google search, or reading the list of Related Questions that pops up. Spend a couple of days doing _actual_ research. Read. Peruse. Think. Understand.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I totally agree. That's how I do it. But look at all the question on SO that do not get closed nor downvoted to hell. I somehow doubt they all spent days doing actual research. In practice the threshold for good enough research for an acceptable question here is much lower, more like how I described it (or even below).

Comment: @Trilarion: Indeed, many people are very forgiving. That's not necessarily "most" people, though: there's an observation bias. I'd guess that _most_ people wish _those_ people would stop being so damned helpful ;)

Comment: In about half the cases I've seen this comment it's been partially or completely irrelevant. In the other cases it's not been very helpful, usually more like distracting noise than helpful.

Answer (score 40):

> in practically every C/C++ question he sees

Certainly not, these are cherry picked!

---

That stock comment was designed very consciously and for valid reasons. I've been putting efforts into that, and it's being created because we see many questions coming in at the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, that simply miss these basic techniques to solve the problems mentioned.

I'm mostly using that along a close vote and downvote. Many people are crying out for why there are no comments given with that. So I'm a nice person, and give them a reasoning.

> Most of the people posting these questions are newbies who need lots of hand-holding to figure out what their problem is.

That's probably the culprit why their questions turn out to be off-topic.

> I've asked him not to post this comment when it's inappropriate, but he just keeps on doing it. He says he uses this stock comment because he's gotten tired of posting more specific comments, but is that really a valid excuse?

It turned out to be useful to identify most of these problems could be solved as *simple typographical* or other trivially solvable errors (e.g using the debugger in 1st place before asking).

We're not meant to nanny every newbie user throughout the basics of a programming language IMO. I'm giving good reference how they could solve these kind of problems themselves in my stock comment.

I'm going to keep that stock comment for the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag (not to mention you don't really have a gold badge there). If I see better options I'd bail out bad questions as being a duplicate.

Comment: If they're typo questions, vote to close them with that reason.

Comment: @Barmar It's not always clear about their 1st shot.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo in the stock comment. There's an extraneous `]` after `by Eric Lippert)`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's true. I'm still having problems to setup that silly <snippets> tool regarding that :P

Comment: @Barmar I think I fixed that now.

Comment: First they complain because you downvote without leaving a comment. Now they complain about the comment you leave. You just can't win!

Comment: @CodyGray Better the latter. (Hey that rhymes ;) ) I rarely seen someone complaining (besides Barmar) BTW.

Comment: By the way, I think you don't need to add the ending that it's a stock comment, that's just noise.

Comment: @DavidG It's changed meanwhile.

Comment: Great. For info I think it's a good comment. I believe teaching people how to answer things for themselves gives them the most powerful skill in their arsenal.

Comment: I just checked some occurences of the comment. It's okay, although I recommend more specific and shorter advice. However the questions in question are almost always of the awful sort, except maybe for the how many times is this struct copied. I would actually like to see an answer (even with a range of possible copy invocations and why they happen or do not happen).

Comment: Here it is [How many copies will this code perform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047704/how-many-copies-will-this-code-perform) unfortunately already closed as unclear although I think it is very clear.

Comment: @Trilarion That's not clear at all and depends both on how the function is called and on compiler optimization. It also potentially depends on which version of C++ we are talking about. All this essential information is missing.

Comment: @BaummitAugen But that makes the question clear, doesn't it? The answer is a number which depends on how the function is called on which compiler optimizations are set. Could an answer not just describe this relation? (I will adapt the question a bit more.)

Comment: @Trilarion Given the information in the question, the answer is "at least 0". Not very helpful if you ask me. One can also not simply iterate over all optimization settings of every C++ compiler. That information is essential.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I would say this is not the full answer but only part of it. What I mean by all this is that this question looks as if I could learn something from it. But if you guys want to have it stock commented on, downvoted and closed - fine by me. I just want to express my opinion.

Comment: @Trilarion With your edit the question is still too broad. (Expressing my opinion here.)

Comment: Since I was curious about the `™` and the meaning of "πάντα ῥεῖ", I googled it and found out [this very relaxing video about NY city](https://vimeo.com/37145156). Seems like a good motivational video for zen debugging :)

Comment: I just upvoted and starred this question, as it's a question devoted to @πάνταῥεῖ. ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: _"Better the latter. (Hey that rhymes ;) )"_ No it doesn't!

Comment: @Lightness Off by a nuance (not to say accent) may be :) You know _[Pumuckl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumuckl)_ do you?

Comment: It would be better if we could point to a FAQ as in the good old [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) days, but in absence of that stock comments are fine. The [C tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) has the beginning of it (sections *"Before you start"* and *"Important notes that may save you time*"), but it is not quite there yet. The same with the [C++ tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) (sections *"Have a Question?"* and *"Stack Overflow's C++ FAQ"*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not trying to cover **every** bad question with that stock comment, if you read my answer more thouroughly :) And we have all that stuff you mention at hands already.

Answer (score 34):

Looks like a reasonable comment to me, *as long as it is posted to questions where it actually applies*.
I find myself leaving *ad hoc* comments like this frequently.

If "stock" comment implies the indiscriminate posting of this to all C++ questions, then no, that's obviously unacceptable. But I monitor the C++ tag, and although it gets so many questions I probably don't even see a quarter of them, I haven't seen πάντα ῥεῖ plaster this all over the place indiscriminately like this question seems to imply.

Otherwise, as a grammar nerd, there are a few things about the phrasing that bother me. I'd rephrase it as follows (which also makes it sound slightly nicer):

> The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

There is obviously no guarantee that leaving such a comment will elicit the desired response, or even any response at all. But I cannot see how it hurts to make the suggestion. At a minimum, it serves as an explanation for why the question is accumulating downvotes and close votes.

Comment: THX for your improvement proposals: I'll adopt these soon.

Comment: And not even the slightest critique about my ™ joke :)

Comment: No, he doesn't post it in *all* C++ questions. I guess my problem is that he doesn't even take the effort to edit out the parts that don't apply to the current question. So it asks for an MCVE even when one is provided, and refers to the debugger even for "how to" questions (as opposed to "why isn't this working" questions).

Comment: @Cody Sorry for the pings, I had to test the updated version somewhere ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is a good point: including irrelevant things in your stock comment can make it worse than useless.  Can you make your script to post it have checkboxes?  (( ) missing MCVE ( ) needs DEBUGGING ( ) Code does not compile) -- then add/remove sentences/phrases based on the checkboxes?

Comment: @Yakk It's a very poor script actually (not mine).