# Will my answer be visible to people even if my reputation is very low?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

I am new to Stack Overflow and have answered a few questions, but I am not getting much response. So I have a question: are my answers visible to people or not?

Comment: From what I can see in your answers (with the qualification that I’m not equipped to judge most of them on a technical level), you’ll be fine in the long run, once you’ve become acquainted with the quirks of how the place works (and most importantly, can leave comments). I also like your tendency to not spoon-feed people who are just too lazy to do the work themselves. Welcome, and just keep on posting good answers - it’ll work out!

Comment: What kind of *response* do you expect?

Comment: I've been a StackOverflow user for 6 years. At first, my reputation increased very slowly, but now that I have ~85 questions and ~70 answers, I get an upvote on one of my old posts about once a week, meaning that my reputation keeps climbing even when I'm not active. Once you've made a few dozen posts, the same thing will happen to you. Occasionally, an answer that you had completely forgotten about after months or years will get a stray upvote!

Comment: Also note that we don't talk about Stack Overflow on SO itself. Meta SO is the place for talking about SO.

Comment: @Kevin And occasionally, you look back on the answer and cringe at your old self, then revise the answer to make it better.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I have hundreds of answers that got no attention from the OP because he asked and never came back to check the answer

Comment: I am proud of my "Unsung Hero" badge. Answers on more basic questions are especially likely to go without upvotes/accepts, in my experience.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, unlike questions, which might be hidden from the front page pending [Triage review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), answers will always be visible. Your first post (answer or question) gets even *more* attention; it will be reviewed in the [First Posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts), so it will get more attention, but after that, your posts will be treated just as a normal user.

Answer (score 14):

It was already mentioned that anwers are indeed visible.

However, here is something on what you can expect on this site:

- **Questions** have a high probability of getting one or more answers/comments in response
- **Answers** have a small probability of getting comments (typically when something is not clear). In addition to this an answer can get accepted if the asker thinks it is the best answer that was provided.

Both good answers and questions are expected to get votes, but this can happen over time, and not always in large quantities.

Comment: Large quantities (at least with any sort of speed) are actually quite rare, even in heavily trafficked tags. My experience has been a score over 5 is unusual and over 10 nearly unheard of. The volume of posts is just too large for lots of eyes to see your answer and vote on it.

Comment: My mean answer score in "primary" tags, excluding outliers varies from 1 to 1.5, but there are a *lot* of zeros.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: "unheard of" is an exaggeration, but a score of >=10 is rare enough to earn you a badge.

Comment: @JDB By "nearly unheard of" I simply meant out of my many answers, I would guess less than 50 and possibly less than 20 are that high

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's his meta profile. His SO profile has 16 answers with a score of 10 or more: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=1 And that's out of 1,139 answers.

Comment: @Nateowami Argh, good point!