# Would you choose unsalvageable in this case? What about reasons for flagging?

Tags: discussion

Going through [triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/2909897), I came across the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42406014/2909897) shown below.

Based on the [unofficial triage guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/2909897) it seemed to me like a clear case of `Unsalvagable`. However, it doesn't seem like it fits into any of the given categories:

[image]

I ended up choosing `unclear what you're asking` because there isn't a question.

What would you choose?

Comment: not sure what you can see in triage but the OP deleted all the content in an edit and replaced it with *"Problem solved by myself but cannot delete it"*, there was a proper question there before. the edit should been rolled back (i have submitted the edit suggestion)

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it I am able to see the `edited x hours ago` option so it was probably there for this question also but I didn't see it at the time. In the future, if that happens should I assume the edit will get rolled back and rate it based the version before the OP edited it?

Comment: Also, I think I might be misunderstanding you because looking through the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42406014/revisions) I only see edits from the OP with no other suggestions.

Comment: in my opinion yes but i would also go about rolling it back aswell. and what i mean by edit suggestion is that right now i have an edit suggestion pending for that question with the rollback. if the OP rejects it or rollbacks to the vandalized version i would then flag for a mod who can rollback the edit easier and lock the question from editing if need be

Comment: Is there a difference between the revision history and suggested edits? I don't see your suggestion, I also don't see it in the [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) section, so how would I have known there was a suggestion pending?

Comment: a suggested edit is just an edit which needs to be approved . it'll show up in the edit history when it does. i think you can suggest edits from the beginning and then at [2000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) you don't need approval for edits. ofcause the OP gets around this because it's their post

Comment: Right! Reviewing edits is mentioned right there at the bottom. Didn't see it :)