# Please help me stop seeing "what's the best programming language" questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, triage, question-quality

I saw this question earlier today:

[When is the best programming language for web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872436/when-is-the-best-programming-language-for-web-development)

It's deleted, so here's a screenshot, although you could probably get the gist from the title.

[image: Screenshot of deleted question]

I wasn't in a review queue, I was just browsing through newest questions. It seems like I see a question like that almost every day I visit the site, and it makes me sad.

Of course it got closed and deleted quickly, but I'm wondering why I see those kinds of questions at all. I thought questions like that would be sent to triage review, and subsequently end up in close vote review after the proper "unsalvageable" triage review, and then get closed and deleted without ever showing up in newest questions. But when I looked at its timeline, it didn't seem to have been through any review queue.

Please correct me if I'm off on my understanding of how the bad question -> triage -> closed -> deleted flow is supposed to work (I know it includes some possibly excessive optimism about people's ability to review properly), but it seems like the problem was that the question didn't end up in triage to begin with.

Based on what I saw in the flow chart [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), the question's quality score determines whether or not that happens. I don't really know how the quality score works, but I think it would be great if silly combinations of tags could factor into it, so questions tagged with lots of different programming languages would end up in triage somehow.

Out of curiosity, [I made a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/772103/too-many-tags) (sorry I'm not that great at it) based on questions with 3+ of the top language tags, excluding a couple, e.g. JavaScript, that are often combined with others in legit questions. They're not all "best programming language" questions, but there definitely does seem to be a quality trend.

Comment: Low quality posts is strictly for answers, not for questions.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that. I don't do a lot of review. Where do unsalvageable questions go?

Comment: If there's a close vote/flag, the close vote review queue.

Comment: I see. Will they still show up on the main page while they're in the CV queue if they've been reviewed as unsalvageable?

Comment: If they were marked as  unsalvageable in Triage, then they won't show up on the homepage.

Comment: Thanks for the education, @Servy. I edited out my "low quality" error.

Comment: Someone flagged it for closure which would have put it in the cv queue but all the 5 close votes came in under 2 minutes from that so it never made it. As to why it didn't get scored low enough to enter triage *shrugs*.

Comment: @JonClements do you know if tags combinations are included at all when the score is calculated? Or is the question score calculation one of those secret things?

Comment: I don't know how the score is calculated but I don't even see a record on that post that one was.

Comment: @JonClements oh, is that part of the timeline normally? Or is that just something you can see as a moderator?

Comment: To be frank - can't remember where I normally see it and from what page. So might be mod only - not sure. (plus on mobile at now so can't go hunting about and it probably isn't that relevant here anyway)

Comment: Could be that triage doesn't get applied after N many successfully posted questions or the 6 month get to ask "get out of jail free card" trumps it...

Comment: Re _"Please help me stop seeing “what's the best programming language” questions"_: I hear staring at the sun works wonders.

Comment: @TinyGiant haha "Try this..."

Comment: Could we blacklist strings like *"Whats the best [programming language/framework] for [topic]?"* in the title and the question body?

Comment: Don't Panic :-)

Comment: @Servy According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/349538), questions can go in the Low Quality Posts review if they get flagged as very low quality. It's just that that rarely happens so you rarely see questions in that review queue. The only time I've seen questions in the Low Quality Posts queue were audits.

Comment: @chade_ For one, I think there are just too many slightly different ways to say it. But mainly, the problem I see with just prohibiting certain text like that is that _those questions shouldn't be asked here at all_, and that way will just get people to ask it with different words. Someone who would ask a question like that here clearly isn't big on reading and following the rules, so they'll probably ask it somehow. I just think it would be cool for it to never see the light of day. I thought that was kind of the point of triage.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Questions *used* to go in the LQP queue.  They no longer do since the creation of Triage.

Comment: @Servy Then you can edit the answer I linked to to mention that.

Comment: Someone here wants me to be sad. :(

Comment: @Servy but there are still audits showing questions in the LQP queue. That's how you know that it's an audit BTW :)

Comment: It's refreshing to see highly downvoted questions time to time. Then you know what you shouldn't do. And it's unavoidable, because some thousands of peoples aren't going to read stupid manuals before they type in their questions.

Comment: @Sinatr The thing is, the people who are going to ask them _don't see them_. They get closed and deleted within minutes, so the next time someone new comes around to ask the same question, there's no highly downvoted duplicate of it to give them pause. I agree, those questions are going to get asked. I just think they should be automatically directed along the proper path.