# Why are there not automatic comments for the Triage Queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, triage

When reviewing low quality answers (such as link-only answers or questions in the answer section) a comment will be posted automatically with a bit of context and a link to the review. This gives the answerer a clear reason as to why their "answer" is not well received.
Today when reviewing the triage queue, I noticed that the same does not exists for the questions that are getting reviewed from there. I expect the reason to be that the feedback is essentially a flag but I think it would still be nice if there could be some automatic feedback to the user who got the flag.

Another reason I would actually understand would be that there are discussions generally under questions and especially so in case of questions of a new user who received a downvote without comment or similar cases.

Now I am wondering: What is the reason that there is no automatic " - From Review" comment when I flag a post from the Triage Queue?

Comment: Contributors are expected to know how to handle constructive criticism on their post.  Questioners are expected to treat it like a personal attack and lose their marbles.

Comment: Questioners are also appearing in the LQP-Queue (just because they asked a question in the answered section they don't become contributor). I agree on the general expected reaction though.

Comment: IIRC, in another meta discussion someone pointed out that the OP does see something when their question gets a flag or close vote so they do get a message about their question.

Comment: Oh? I have never noticed nor seen anything like that. Then again, I wonder why a comment in case of answers and message for questions (which could be connected to the fact that also unregistered users can post an answer?). Anyway, if you or anyone else could find a reference for that message thing, that would be awesome!

Comment: I think the original idea was that tolerable questions don't need comments, unsalvageable questions get guidance from the close reason message, and questions sent to the Help & Improvement queue would get "help" from the H&I reviewer.

Comment: So it would have to come to the question getting closed in order for the user to see the issue?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Which would make sense, because by that point there is at least a very small consensus about the question. Once in awhile I do see a completely misplaced close vote which doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: The comments from LQP Queue are posted after even less consensus (at least one flag and one reviewer if I understand that system correctly) while a question is closed after 5 (?) close votes. And it happens exactly the same that I go through the LQP Queue and see misplaced "From Review" comments.

Comment: Because most triage reviewers are Doing It Wrong in one way or another, and that would be far too much noise and nonsense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the beautiful flow-chart Shog9 made in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)

[image: a flow chart by Shog]

There are only a few outcomes from Triage:

1. **Looks OK:** There is nothing wrong with this post, reviewers need not comment on this in triage.
2. **Should be improved:** The Help and Improvement / Helper queue deals with these posts.
3. **Unsalvageable:** This goes to the mod/close queue. Questions will be closed when needed, with appropriate feedback on what is wrong with the post, and what steps to take to get a question reopened.

The review queue Low Quality Posts is more intended to explicitly target low quality posts, from mostly new users, guiding them on why their answer is not up to our standards helps to educate them.

If we would do the same in Triage, and a post then being kicked to either H & I or Close, would double up the feedback, IMHO that would be an overkill.

Comment: Oh this makes a lot more sense with that flowchart (I never knew that this is how the questions work here!). So essentially the idea is that the LQP is supposed to give feedback and so are H&I + the Close Queue which are the only ways a question can go if it is not ok already hence no feedback from Triage is required?

Comment: This flowchart obviously doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Why would you think that @Xan-KunClark-Davis?

Comment: The quality and the way SO is used has changed dramatically over the last year or two. Apart from just being out of date (there is no "unsalvageable" option anymore).