# Could we get a special warning in triage, when question gets flagged as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, triage

*Well, that's quite an uninteresting title. Many of you might be thinking, why would we even need such a thing, well hear me out...*

---

Now, I probably won't be the only one who will be surprised by a following factoid.
Recently I did re-read  the [guide to triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) and there was this one detail that completely escaped my memory upon my initial read.

> First, there's a bit of a special case here: Duplicates. A clear,
>   well-written question might still be a duplicate, **and the last thing
>   you want to do is to dispute Duplicate flags by choosing Looks OK if
>   it is a duplicate.** So always read the comments first: scroll to the
>   end of the question, and if you see "Possible duplicate" in the list,
>   either mark it as a duplicate yourself (if you can confirm that the
>   comment is accurate) or Requires Editing if the author has provided
>   some clarification in the comments but hasn't yet edited the post;
>   **choose Looks OK only if you're certain the question is not a
>   duplicate**. As always, Skip is a fine option here if you simply don't
>   want to take the time to look at duplicates.

Now yes, technically this is my fault for not being more attentive and memorizing this, but when you're new to reviews you get possibly quite overwhelmed with all the new things and guides.

**My point is a smart & good design should not account for user's responsibility**. But it should follow, *one of my favourite corporate buzzwords* - poka-yoke   - or in normal speech - be foolproof! Especially when the issue at hand is potentially so easy to fix.

I'm thinking something along the lines of something simple and intuitive like this:

[image]

> <sup>Obviously, just an illustration. Design/content is subject to
>   change</sup>

I feel like it fits in naturally and mentions a very important information people might otherwise overlook or be straight up not aware of. And even if people are aware of the fact, how they should judge the 'duplicate triage reviews, if you're clogging through them, there still is a good chance you might overlook a comment about it by accident.

**It's not intrusive, it teaches newer users and it even helps veterans make better decisions**

Comment: Your illustration doesn't seem to have a way to confirm that the question is a duplicate. I assume there should be one.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Now that I think about it yeah.Weird thing is, it is not even stated in the official guide what to do if you want to confirm the duplicity flag. I presume re-flagging it as unsalavageable with the same duplicate flag (?)

Comment: If you're <3K rep you'd best flag again to make it complete triage. If you're >3K rep flags are automatically converted to close votes and you can and should cast a close vote agreeing with the duplicate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The *actual* fix for this problem is to remove the functionality to dispute duplicate flags just because the triage users didn't vote to close it as a duplicate, because that's not what people in that queue are typically looking for.

As long as the duplicate flag sticks around regardless of the Triage action, we don't really care what people in Triage do, so there's no need for warnings for people in Triage to not notice.

Comment: The _actual_ actual fix would be to get rid of triage.

Comment: @TinyGiant Showing posts that the given heuristics have determined are more likely to be bad than other questions in front of people and asking them if they should be closed is a reasonable enough thing to do.  Honestly the whole invalidating of flags *ever* is probably rather suspect, but putting some potentially bad questions in front of people and giving them a chance to flag them isn't a useless queue.  It's not like H&I that is just literally pointless and so far from being salvageable that it'd be better to start from scratch.

Comment: we did all of that before Triage, and we can still do it all after triage. We don't need to put such content in front of low rep users who don't have a grasp of the topicality of stack overflow to categorize it.

Comment: Also... Triage without the H&I is... not triage.

Comment: Triage without H&I is the close votes queue, but prioritizing new questions.  (Which we should just do in the close votes queue.)

Comment: @TinyGiant By that logic we should just remove all of the review queues, because the site once existed without them.  As I said, triage without H&I is evaluating suspicious new questions *before they're shown on the homepage*, and giving people a chance to flag them.  If they're flagged for a mod, a mod can look at it before it goes to the homepage, if they're flagged for closure it can go to the close queue before it goes to the homepage.  Triage was created a while before H&I existed.  It was honestly a better queue before H&I was added.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The close queue only ever evaluates a fairly small fraction of posts sent to it already.  It's currently only sent posts that are flagged or voted for closure, and most just age out of the queue.  If you try to add to that questions from new users that *might* merit closure you'll just end up with those all aging out of the queue too.  It's also not a good queue for flagging posts that have a problem other than closure.

Comment: And due to the fact that it can't address most posts sent to it, and the fact that it takes a long time to evaluate those that *are* sent to it, you realistically couldn't prevent the questions currently shown to triage from going to the homepage if they were sent to the close queue, as they'd stay in limbo for *days* or even *weeks* before the queue either gets to them or they age out.

Comment: @Servy we had a review queue for low quality questions before we had triage, or do you forget that when triage was made the questions were removed from the LQPRQ? I mean, if we want to go all reductio ad absurdum here then we should just get rid of Stack Overflow because everyone got by without it before it came along. No, don't be ridiculous.

Comment: Also... you still have not explained how triage could possibly be triage without the H&I. Without the H&I, triage would just be a Low Quality Questions Queue exposed to new users who don't know anything about the site. Yeah, go ahead and keep trying to defend that.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't really have a problem with low quality questions and low quality answers being separated into different queues.  They're handled differently enough that it seems worthwhile.  You're the one who argued that we should get rid of it just because we used to not have it.  That's a ridiculous argument.  Demonstrating that it's ridiculous, isn't ridiculous.  If you could argue that low quality questions were handled better before it existed, then that would be an argument worth making.

Comment: @TinyGiant How have I not explained how triage could be triage without H&I?  I've explained it several times.  In fact, it existed before H&I existed, for quite some time in fact.  Since you seem to have forgotten, it'd be a place where potentially bad questions would go, before being shown on the homepage, to either get flagged or marked as okay and sent to the homepage.  There is in fact a purpose to triage besides sending posts to H&I.  Yes, that does make it more or less a low quality questions queue.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Servy [I'm pretty sure the H&I and triage were created at the same time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/4639281), but whatever. And no, you have not explained how triage can possibly fit the model of what triage is: _"Those who are likely to live, regardless of what care they receive;
Those who are likely to die, regardless of what care they receive;
Those for whom immediate care might make a positive difference in outcome."_ without the H&I.  If you take away one of the outcomes, it ain't triage no more.

Comment: @TinyGiant H&I was *planned* when Triage came out.  It came out some time later though.  Sure, if you want to be technical, it would become Biage if you changed it, as there would only be two options, not three.  But it would still be a useful queue.  Your assertion that the whole queue would be pointless is quite false, even if it's only putting things into two buckets instead of three.  If you want to petition for the name to be changed as well, go nuts.  Personally I don't care if the name changes or not.