# Why not merge Triage and First Post queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, first-post-review

I'm pretty new to moderating but it seems like the problems uncovered by Triage and First Post are usually the same:

- Some bad questions that can be edited by others to make work
- Other bad questions that can only be improved by the questioner (e.g. missing code) where you might like to ask the questioner to do so in the comments
- Some bad questions that deserve to be downvoted or immediately closed because they are so bad
- Some good questions that can be upvoted

To me, the division in possible actions between Triage and First Post seems somewhat arbitrary. In First Post you can do anything except vote to close (you can even write an answer if you follow the link). In Triage you are limited to voting to close, and marking it for somebody else to edit later.

The main reason for my suggestion is that I think an option is missing from Triage: Requires editing *by the question asker*. If you see something like that in First Post, you can simply say in a comment "please improve your post, e.g. by [including missing code etc]", you get credit for the review action, and the question asker gets helpful feedback. Whereas if you see a similar post in Triage, you can still add a similar comment, but you will have to Skip and you won't get credit. So it pushes people toward the more aggressive action of "Unsalvageable." Note also that no credit is given for adding a comment explaining to somebody what their post is missing.

"Requires Editing" sounds like what you'd want, but that's only if it requires editing by somebody else. Again, technically you should mark it as "Unsalvageable" since it's missing important information, but that runs counter to the goal of helping the person improve their question without closing.

If these two queues were merged into a single queue where all options were available and all options were given credit, you would not have this problem.

Although, it may be that I'm mistaken and that we DO want to close the question until the person improves it. If so then there's no problem, but I'd still ask why not give somebody the option to improve and only close if they fail to do so. Call me a bleeding heart :). Also in that case it's worth asking why the close option isn't available from First Post.

Comment: First posts are for new contributors which we should "Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering. Check out our Code of Conduct."

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [The “First Posts” review queue is ineffective and toothless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170586/165773) TL;DR: we already tried that and results turned out awful

Comment: "option is missing from Triage: Requires editing by the question asker" is what vote-to-close is for. If the editong is good enough,  it will be reopened.

Answer (score 7):

> In First Post you can do anything except vote to close

You can still *flag* a question for closure, and the outcome is *the same* as in the Triage review queue. The main difference is that in Triage, this option is more emphasized, but that's for a reason; the [Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/4751173) gets fed by an algorithm that selects questions it deems to be of low quality (and, less often, by Very Low Quality flags from users). First Posts will see all sorts of posts, good and bad, as long as it's the first post of the user. It's just that most new users aren't familiar with Stack Overflow standards, so on average their first posts aren't really good.

> The main reason for my suggestion is that I think an option is missing from Triage: *Requires editing by the question asker.*

That's exactly what "Unsalvageable" means, and really, if you come across such a question in the First Posts queue, you should not only leave a comment, but flag it for closure as well. Note that closing a question will first put it On Hold; this will display a banner with some resources for improving the question, and if *somebody* edits it into a better shape within five days, it will end up in the Reopen review queue.

Think of a comment as a way for making a new user familiar with the rules, and of a closure flag as a way of *enforcing* said rules.