# What is a triage question?

Tags: support

I was looking at the review page for Stack Overflow, and I came across a triage question. This then made me ask myself, what is a triage question? Can anyone tell me what one is?

Comment: A triage question is a question that is in the triage review queue. The triage review queue is a review queue intended for users to triage questions based on flags from other users and automatic heuristics.

Comment: The original announcement of the triage queue: *[Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380)* (includes an explanation for the term "triage")