# What causes a Triage review to be invalidated?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

As a motivating example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63718141/timeline)'s Triage review was invalidated at 2020-09-03 22:52:03Z, a time that does not appear to correspond exactly to any other event in the post's history (including the one upvote it has received as of this posting).

I know that closing a question (or, presumably, deleting it) will cause the review to be invalidated.  What other events can cause this?  In this example, did the First Post review being completed as No Action Needed cause it to be invalidated?  Was it the upvote?

More generally, what are the events that can cause a Triage review to be invalidated?

Comment: I remember someone somewhere saying that there's a limit in how many active triage reviews there would be at a given time and how much time can a post be in review. Someone might need to check the source code for that since I couldn't find the reference.

Comment: Are you sure about the invalidation time you mention here in the question? Given that the time you mention is many hours after you posted this question, and edited it, it appears the time stated here is wrong. To me, both logged in and in a private window, the timeline shows 2020-09-03 07:22:55Z as the timestamp for the Triage invalidation. That is very close to the 07:18:16 of the upvote, but even closer to the 2020-09-03 07:21:28Z "No Action Needed" result from the First posts review.

Comment: Given that the Triage review was initiated simultaneously with the question being asked, I assume it was pushed into Triage due to its [Q-score being below the threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/3773011). Presumably, either or both of the "No Action Needed" First Posts result and/or the upvote triggered a reevaluation of the question wrt. Q-score and the current state of the question (e.g. upvoted) resulted in it no longer being qualified for auto-inclusion in Triage, so the Triage review was invalidated.