# When will a post enqueue Triage review type?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I notice that there is a new review type `Triage` today!

Good job, I think this will be a significant way to improve the qualities of  review activities.

But I'm wondering, when will a post enqueue to that review type?

I just want to know more about that, plz help.

Answer (score 10):

When the system gets spooked.

The System is normally a very calm, trusting beast. But you gotta approach it in the right way. If you sneak up behind it, or yell at it loudly, or hit it over the head with a stick repeatedly, it gets kinda skittish. And then it sends your questions into Triage.

Right now, we're still adjusting the *exact* criteria for posts being sent into triage, so I'm reluctant to document them in detail. But here are a few of the things we're looking at:

- Author reputation
- Author past history
- Author's network's past history
- How often the author bangs their head against a wall before posting.
- [Magic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267778/details-of-the-quality-score-algorithm-as-discussed-in-the-recent-podcast/267788#267788)

Comment: How big of a stick?